# Why doesn't Stack Overflow default to SSL?

Tags: discussion, ssl

Why doesn't http://www.stackoverflow.com redirect to https://www.stackoverflow.com?

Is there a reason SSL is not enforced?

Comment: Try putting https:// in front of the URL for this question, and see what happens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey works fine for me.

Comment: Awesome. *[goes to the store to get some cookies, since I can't steal Mathews']*

Comment: Because TLS costs money (in CPU usage) and everything you do on this site is public anyway?

Comment: SSL is not supported yet. It's still in testing / they're putting it together. Not everything on the network is designed or built to work with SSL yet and they can't enforce it until *everything* is ready to go.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That is not how “public” works. Not. Even. Close. (And even if it were, as a moderator, no, not everything I do is public.) See also https://istlsfastyet.com/. Mathew: There are some bugs to iron out; mixed content, chat not working, and the like.

Comment: So it sounds like you guys are working on it. Cool.

Comment: Any news about the SO and SSL? I have just tried the https but it still does not work.

Comment: @minitech "GitHub Pages is temporarily down for maintenance." Oh, ok.

Comment: I see this question has a reopen flag. If this question is reopened and the dupe link is lost, here is a link to some relevant info for posterity: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270642/616460