# https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-deferred, ssl

Not sure if this is the right place to report this, but here are a couple of minor points:

1. If I navigate to https://www.stackoverflow.com it redirects me to http://stackoverflow.com.
   I would have expected it to redirect to https://stackoverflow.com
2. If I connect to https://stackoverflow.com, the links to questions use https as expected.  But links to featured meta questions use http - I would have expected https.

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites  and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226030/roadmap-for-https-ssl-support

Comment: Definitely related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268249/improper-https-connection-only-partially-encrypted

Comment: Also related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223728/permalink-short-urls-lose-https

Comment: I guess I'm too dumb to understand. What exactly about stack supporting SSL is going to be of help, other than a false peace of mind? I don't feel insecure in the slightest that it is just a regular http site. There is nothing about the content of stack that I need secured.

Comment: @Gimby - A good reason would be an ISP injecting ads onto the page. Which is what the majority of ISPs in my country are doing. HTTPS stops this.

Comment: @Gimby: It is called "Stack Overflow", not "stack". And what business is it of anyone else what I am reading on Stack Overflow? It's great that you don't care but many of us do. More cynically, I don't think we need people's freely sourced / stolen code quietly replaced with hax by a MITM.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the past months since that comment I've called the site Stack Overflow plenty of times, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Gimby: You're welcome

Answer (score 44, accepted):

We don't have full SSL support yet, although it's in the works. Nick blogged about some of the challenges last year [here](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).

Comment: I'm surprised that those challenges amount to a year's worth of work...

Comment: @BradWerth calendar-time !== development-time

Comment: @BradWerth This is a pretty acurate time table of dev time: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Time

Comment: Reading that blog, it looks like not being able to use SNI is a major factor (also note that a cert with 100 SANs can be quite large and introduce some overhead). The wilcard problem could have been solved if the system had been designed to be able to use a prefix in the path, e.g. `http://something.stackexchange.com/meta/` instead of `http://meta.something.stackexchange.com/`.

Comment: @BradWerth It's almost like we have other things we're working on as well. :)

Comment: AdamLear, No doubt. I'm not criticizing, just genuinely surprised. I'm sure you could knock it out in a week, were it a priority. It sounds like the biggest hurdle is an architectural decision, as @Bruno has highlighted, rather than a whole pile of development.

Comment: Related question (currently unanswered): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284129/default-to-https-links-when-using-imgur-links

Comment: almost Mai 2016. Still "a lot of work"?

Comment: What's the status of the HTTPS migration?

Comment: @PaulSchreiber "Work in progress". We're paying down a lot of tech debt along the way, so things are moving slower than we'd like. Nick Craver's on it, though.

Answer (score 11):

I use the [HTTPS Everywhere extension](https://www.eff.org/Https-everywhere) and the links stay HTTPS.

Comment: @GrantWinney: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284129/default-to-https-links-when-using-imgur-links

Comment: The extension is unavailable for some browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Can we remove all absolute urls like this one...

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/..." ...>
```

And make them protocol relative:

```
<a href="//stackoverflow.com/questions/..." ...>
```

That can be done independently and should offer a smooth transition when you fully support SSL.

Comment: Another one which I noticed is browse to SSL
https://stackoverflow.com/
then click on the Achievements in the navbar, and select any item, you will be at a non secure endpoint then.