# What's StackEgg?

Tags: discussion, stackegg

This recently showed up on Stack Overflow.

What does it mean? Why is this image showing here! What is StackEgg?

[image: StackEgg]

Comment: Check the date. (allowing +/- 12 hours to be on the safe side)

Comment: I'm on day 50: `50 days have elapsed` :D

Comment: It's the **new Area51!**. You first have to break the internet and then you are allowed to make a new proposal on Area51. That's the new system :)

Comment: Can't repeat, but first time (see why) it seemed to some odd things. Like not close the initial image once I'd clicked-and-realised; having gone through to the image with the X to close, it wouldn't close. Tried on another computer as well - doesn't even appear there :-)

Comment: OK, so only appears when inside a question :-) The rest is probably cashing (in on April Fools' Day)

Comment: I get it. Brilliant idea. There's a randomiser which makes different things happen for the same user. Thus, any reported bugs are Staus-by-Desgin. Got me all confused for several Samoan minutes.

Comment: @BillWoodger Really it's awesome!!! I loving it.

Comment: I'm disappointed they didn't call it Stackmagotchi

Comment: Whatever it is it seems to be dragging down the response times on the site. Everything is taking much longer to load.

Comment: Ok, It's a joke, I get that, It's not funny though...Like I just don't get it, last years was better.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, I noticed it this morning also Sam. Another thing I noticed is that something's not right, being taking forever for questions to load, message notifications etc. What gives? Total turn-off. TBH, I've no more gas left in my tractor at Farmville; a good thing I've lost my way how to get there.

Comment: If I had any more Angry Birds I would aim them at the egg. @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard *An error occured while voting* - Oh, way to go Flo! Got any extra ammo?

Comment: Is it only me or has the site been slowing down since the appearance of this egg?

Comment: Wasn't there an April Fools opt-out in preferences or was it just a sweet, sweet dream?

Comment: And [Game Development Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) is the first site to win the Internet!!

Comment: @Juhana Seriously i don't know what happened? but my SO is running very very slow (it's taking 20 sec to load an notification).

Comment: @Juhana I just added the way to disable to the answers below. Site speed seems to have improved some.

Comment: Anybody wanna buy a used tractor? You'll need to put in some gas though. Tires might be a little low too. If you can find Farmville on the map; good luck.

Comment: The perf problems exist even on pages without this widget. Try to load the comment thread under this question. It's slow. Looks like backend overload.

Comment: Actually the Stack Egg is just a decoy. The *real* April Fools is the huge performance hit the sites are experimenting.

Comment: I must just be getting old and crotchety, because regardless of April Fools or bad performance, I thought it was stupid and immediately disabled it.

Comment: April Fools?! It's March 31st!!!

Comment: @jakekimds, [not everywhere](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/russia/anadyr).

Comment: I think SE deserves credit for making this year's game much less hackable than last year's.  At least, I _think_ this time around there's not a JavaScript one-liner that can be used to cheat/(successfully/optimally) autoplay.

Comment: It totally killed my productivity (o.O)

Comment: last year unicorn coins... this year StackEggs `:P`

Comment: Happy April fool day! to all of us by stackoverflow :D

Comment: @MayankPatel Seriously SO made me April Fool Yesterday!!!! damn men!!!  _even my girl friend never makes me April fool!!!_

Comment: @MD yup but this site more helping us compare to girl friend

Comment: @MayankPatel That's correct all the way!!!! BTW _Happy April Fool day!!!!_

Comment: @MD same to you

Comment: I'm kind of bummed about this site simulator.  When I saw the title, I was hoping I could raise my very own Jon Skeet.

Comment: Its so interesting how every April fools day theres a giant meta post about what the new feature is... when SE consistently releases something weird on April Fools day. You'd think we would have learned by now...

Comment: @samy: only because that sound quite like a disease :)

Comment: I absolutely love the close reason.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you find the Egg is slowing you down too much:

1. Click on the Stack Egg to open its dialog box.
2. Click the question mark in the upper right hand corner.
3. Check the two checkboxes on the right hand side, under the egg.
4. ?????
5. Profit!

[image]

Does this mean that I win the Internet for speeding it back up?

Comment: Your trick is worked!!! Now SO is working pretty fast.

Comment: It helped about 2%, but I'll take everything I can get.

Comment: I noticed that a couple of things are still really slow @Fred-ii- but everything else seems to have come up to "normal".

Comment: [`define("NORMAL", "Whose normal?");`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Comment: `'normal' !== 'me'` @Fred-ii-

Comment: *The connection was reset* - Oh, just lovely. Yo Flo(w), get that thing fixed eh? *Groan*. Hey Sam; I'm out of ammo, gimme some more will ya buddy? ;-)

Comment: @Tanner There is a re-enable button in the footer

Comment: *I'm right there with you Ralph, running low myself.* Maybe, if we all get off the site it'll speed back up @Fred-ii-. We could always come back on Thursday or something. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Some body get me out from this SO. **Totally dispointed of OverFlow**.

Comment: You'd swear I was on a 2400 baud modem. The corner store has a faster connection with their debit card moh-sheen. Thursday? Ah, that's a bad day for me Sam.

Comment: Where was this answer an hour ago when I hid the damn thing with AdBlock? +1 to SE for implementing an opt-out, -1 for hiding it in a "help" menu.

Comment: Stack is sick, pass it on and tell them that the deal they THINK they got on 2400 baud modems, wasn't a deal after all.

Comment: @MD, IMO, you should not accept this answer as it does not answer the question.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ya i know but it's doesn't matter. becoz it's also part of _April Fool_. hehehehe

Answer (score 119):

StackEgg was a failed April Fools joke that killed the site's performance.

Comment: That it most definitely did.

Comment: That's a lot of work to go into a failed April Fools joke.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding, especially with stuff like this - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270642/525478 . Now I know why it's taking so long...

Comment: It's not even April yet...

Comment: If only there were some kind of a Q & A site for programming where they could have gone to for advice to implement it properly.

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral They could try, but the question would be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Woodface Or it would turn into a semantic argument over whose implementation is better and why Hungarian notation is the bestest.  */s

Comment: That's where the word *backfire* comes into *play*.

Comment: Maybe killing the site's performance was the real April Fools joke all along? StackEgg is just there to convince you it was unintentional.

Comment: I don't even get the joke.

Comment: Failed? No way. Just another layer of entertainment... internally. https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/582995063141068802

Answer (score 45):

The trick is to find a lightly trafficked SE site so that you can do a solo playthrough.

[image]

It looks like someone on the Amateur Radio site had the same idea:

[image]

Now the real question is, what's the awesome prize for having the fastest Stack Egg?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was software recommendations for me, although it was public already when I played :).

Comment: "what's the awesome prize for having the fastest Stack Egg" - that site doesn't get deleted tomorrow ;p

Comment: I did a playthrough on expats.se as well. It's easier than doing it jointly with others, but it's also less fun to do it a second time

Comment: @SztupY - I completely agree.  The single-player campaign has very little replay value.  At least with multiplayer you get to wonder what the hell people are thinking.  It would be even better with integrated chat.

Comment: @martin that was me who made softwarerecs public :) and I was pretty surprised when I returned and it was won already

Comment: I got a 266 on Writers, but someone started it, and used a flag.

Comment: So  bored doing this on Pets; I quit.

Comment: Someone on Cross Validated got 252.  Well done.

Comment: @martin Hey me too! I guess we're the two times that got SoftRec to win the internet.

Comment: Should stream live on twitch and then export to youtube as a lets play

Comment: I was the one with the idea of playing solo on Amateur Radio;-)

Answer (score 20):

I can think of nothing but a new way to wish **"April Fool"**.

There is a song in Hindi which says:

`April Fool Banaya
To Tujko Gussa AAya
Isme Mera Kya Kasur
Ye Hai Jamane Ka Uusul
April Fool Banaya`

English Translation:

`We made you April Fool
You got Angry
Its Not My Fault
Its famous culture/ritual of our society
 We made you April Fool`

Comment: @An i think you're right!!! men SO made me **April Fool** !! Dman bad men!!!

Comment: The real punchline is that 'Game Development Stack Exchange' has and shall retain the top spot on the leaderboard.

Comment: Many more April returns of the year LOL!!

Comment: Whoops, guess I'm April Fools now.

Answer (score 9):

It's **StackEgg**. Quoting from the help page which appears when you press <kbd>?</kbd> at the right side of the title bar,

> Welcome to StackEgg, a completely realistic simulation of the growth of a Stack Exchange site! Start from your pet Site's birth on Area 51, witness it grow through private beta and public beta, until that special day when your once-little Site finally graduates as a fully-featured Q&A site, ready to take on the task of becoming the best site on the internet.
>
> Hatch your Site, help it grow, get it through tough times, and tame a gotcha or two that inevitably appear when a site grows.

It's actually a game which you play with other users who have registered on that particular site. In this game, you "hatch your virtual pet Stack Exchange Site through all stages of its life" and the main objective is to grow a healthy site by keeping all the hearts filled.

Comment: "completely realistic" that sums up everything, nice april guys

Answer (score 5):

I must admit I enjoyed playing with StackEggs !

That being said, this is social simulation aimed at better knowing the priorities of the SE network users (regarding site quality, notably) -- and the determine how to spend the [money recently raised](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/).

Definitively not an April's Fool Joke, but a very serious business indeed...

Comment: I don't think so... really!!!! @Sylvain Leroux

Comment: And here I thought it was to teach people the importance of upvoting questions!

Answer (score 0):

It's an unknown entity and will conquer the world.

By the way: nice April to everybody.