# Unikong DDoS prevention

Tags: discussion, unikong

In the credits of Unikong it's mentioned, that the game has a DDoS prevention.

[image: Credits]

If the game really has this prevention, than how is it done only for the game? Don't you prevent the whole SO from DDoS? Which leads me to the conclusion, that the DDoS prevention of the game would be useless?

Comment: This *may* be a pun related to [the time SO DDOSed itself with an April Fool prank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289032/464709). Special steps *may* have to be taken to prevent that from happening again.

Comment: Why can this no longer be reproduced? I can reproduce it. Go to https://unikong.github.io/, press the down key twice, then press the space key once and you will see "DDOS prevention".