# Getting logged out on switch to http

Tags: support, bug, login, ssl

I get logged out (somewhat randomly or I haven't figured out all the cases) due to the switch from https to http. These are all caused by internal links (such as notifications). Which, I believe is caused by not using protocol less links?

This seems to be a known problem:
[Why doesn't Stack Overflow have HTTPS (SSL)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-have-https-ssl)
and one of the answers suggest to use HTTPS Everywhere extension:
[https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com)

However it says this might lead to problems?

As an alternative, I tried to login to the non https site which turns out to be impossible (I get redirected back to the http version)

Is there any other workaround?

Comment: I retagged your post as bug and Login so a dev can have a look in case something is broken.