# Logging on after going to https://stackoverflow.com redirects to http site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, security, ssl

If I go to `http://stackoverflow.com`, then log in using Google, I am redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com` after I enter my Google credentials.

Shouldn't SE sites respect my initial choice, and redirect to the `https` site after logging in?

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com) from 2014 is related, but refers to a different aspect of the issue.

Comment: @JoeW I link to that question in my question. It is not the same thing in that mine is what happens after I log in.

Comment: @SinanÜnür but the answer is the same..... "We don't have full SSL support yet, although it's in the works. ...."

Comment: @psubsee2003 I disagree. If I log in while viewing a question, I am taking back to that question. So, the problem is not SSL/TLS support -- it is a problem with the redirection logic.

Comment: I would imagine broken redirects for SSL is part of the umbrella of 'not full SSL support'