# UNIKONG development time

Tags: discussion, unikong

How many hours did you guys spend building UNIKONG?

Someone had to ask.

---

It would be nice to see a blog post on its development at some point. Must have been fun.

Comment: Adam Lear was actually in charge of the project. ;P

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I can't believe things like this and StackEgg are prioritized ahead of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com/270642#270642, which has been "in the works" for years.

Comment: @BradWerth to be fair, games like these are trivial little things to be done in their spare time. SSL implementation on SO is looking to be a nightmare, mainly due to the fact that they use urls like meta.*.stackexchange.com rather than *.meta.stackexchange.com, which means they cannot obtain SSL certificates for meta sites.

Answer (score 85):

We started planning in late February. (Google Docs remind me that the initial "gathering ideas" doc had a deadline of February 21.) The idea for the game itself didn't actually come out of that per se, but we landed on that in early March (Google Docs sez... March 4th). At that point I began learning how to even make a game + looking at frameworks that may help us along the way.

At this point, no further Google docs were produced, so the timeline gets a bit hazy... but basically, I ended up settling on [phaser.js](//phaser.io) as the framework of choice about a week later and started prototyping the game. The whole thing took about two weeks of me coding part-time + another week full-time, with Paweł making the artwork in about a week's time and Haney joining in in the last week to help out. (The leaderboard, a bunch of bug fixes, and any particle effects you see are Haney's <s>fault</s> handywork.)

Why part-time? I have the attention span of a squirrel and it is surprisingly hard to drop every other project/bug fix/day-to-day task to work on something brand new. I'm also not sure exactly what Haney's time split was, but we did end up pulling an 18-hour day this past Wednesday. Let's pretend it was to relive college glory and not a result of me getting sick at the wrong time and otherwise suboptimal time management. ;)

All in all, it's hard to put a precise "this took X hours" time on this, but it was in the ballpark of 3 weeks all told. I'm also happy to write up a blog post, though I'm not sure there's all that much to say there. "Phaser is a solid framework with good examples that will get you where you need to go. The rest is magic numbers, copy/pasting, and a designer who knows what he's doing." :)

P.S. I do plan to open-source the game in the near future. I'll update this answer with the link when that happens.

P.P.S.

[image]

Worked out alright in the end, though. :)

Comment: Amazing!!! Thanks for the detail! Would love to see the released OSS!

Comment: More opensource than [it already is](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/unikong.js)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, at least unbundled and unminified. ;)

Comment: I'm really curious to know, why do you think investing 3 weeks work for an April fools gig is a good idea.

Comment: @gdoron Because he's paid to do it, probably.

Comment: @gdoron We plan on liking fun for about a month out of every year. I actually came in under budget!

Comment: @gdoron I think its totally worth it. Little bits of life like this, no matter how trivial, raise regard for a company and make it stand out.

Comment: @AdamLear, I still didn't get why do you think it's a good idea. What cause does it serve? Wouldn't it be much "cheaper" and "funer" taking you all for a trip or playing basketball? I honestly puzzled about it. But I guess different companies - different culture. Still puzzled though...

Comment: @gdoron Every year we do something fun for our users on April 1. That's about it. The cause is providing some lighthearted entertainment and (ideally) brightening someone's day. Taking millions of users out on a trip would be more expensive in the end. :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/unikong.js - unminified (you have to scroll through the Phaser first)

Comment: I'm digging this source code. `clean: function() { console.log('woof'); }`. @AdamLear do you own a dog?

Answer (score 82):

Jon Skeet told the program to write itself.

Comment: You know *Rubber duck debugging?* I've been told some selected folks at SO HQ have a small rubber yellow figure of Mr. JS beside their keyboards. . . . . With that, there's no "debugging", you just program.

Comment: Now I want a JS bobblehead on my desk so bad...

Comment: Oh great. Now whenever I hear JS, I'll think of Jon Skeet instead of JavaScript.

I guess that's why they changed it to ECMAScript?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja They didn't change it to ECMAScript. ECMAScript is just a JavaScript standard.