# Request for redesign to have better compatibility with 1024px-wide displays

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

[The last time the 1024px issue was brought up was in early 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283703/new-page-layout-too-wide-for-1024px). I wonder what the user metrics are now it's 2017.

Personally, while I do have other machines with bigger displays, I'm currently dividing most of my time between my ThinkPad T43 and my ThinkPad X61, which both run at 1024x768. There is an undeniable bit of friction using SO on these due to the omnipresent horizontal scrollbar visible on every page.

Now that the site has been redesigned I thought it might be worth revisiting this old question. In particular, I wanted to point out that the boxes on the right side of edit pages (eg, `#scroller`) are `position:fixed` and *do not horizontally scroll even when they extend off the right of the page*. This diverges somewhat from the (downvoted) official answer in the old thread: "it shouldn't be broken, but we're not going to make it pixel perfect." Well, the theme *is* now broken.

I found it interesting to observe how Jeff Atwood himself popped out of the woodwork to chime in and argue for a responsive design when this was being discussed in January 2015. Food for thought.

**TL;DR**: There (apparently) aren't enough 1024px users to statistically justify a site change. There ***are,*** however, enough users out there that this issue will continue to be quietly brought up every now and again. Fixing this *across the entire Stack Exchange network* for those people would be amazing. :D

Another question: I'm curious what types of metrics you're using. Do you send a new ping on each page load? Browser windows might be different sizes from different visits. The 15" Macbook Pro has a 2880px-wide display... users might want to split SO with their code editor or another window.

Comment: Related: [*Bring back the Ask Question button*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343819/2751851)

Comment: I agree that it is infuriating, that, quite simply, SO doesn't work when you happen to have your browser set a bit narrow.  it's not 1970, we live in the era of responsive design.  I've always simply assumed **SO is broken** in that it doesn't work when you happen to have your browser on say 1000px wide, and I assumed that eventually someone at SO would fix it.  It's simply ***broken***.  Of course, obviously, when you narrow your browser there should be a new layout (move the idiotic right hand column down the bottom, just get rid of it - or whatever solution - "responsive design").

Comment: I agree. I typically have a filtered questions feed open that is resized to fit half of my screen. By default, the site is essentially unusable at that size, so I wrote a custom userscript that makes the site responsive. It condenses the layout and removes a lot of the unnecessary padding/whitespace. It only took about 20 minutes to write the CSS, so I don't understand why SO doesn't even attempt to make the site responsive. Instead, time is prioritized and spent developing the documentation feature and making [April fools games](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320309/2680216).

Comment: @JoshCrozier, yes, you're right about the April fools games. They are sooo incredible expensive in terms of developer time. Nick Craver confirmed that: *[It's so true, we took 43 of our engineers off their projects for about 3 months and they did nothing but Unikong. We think it turned out pretty great though](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339391/is-documentation-failing/339428#comment420656_339428)*. And completed with: *[We'll allocate at least 30% more resources next year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339391/is-documentation-failing/339428#comment420660_339428)*.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, regarding the Documentation feature, it's a bet. They are investing many developer hours to build something big. It can turn out to be a successful feature that will bring more revenue to SO or they can cancel the project to stop losing money. You know, it's business. Every company must *try* to inovate/grow.

Comment: @Zanon - Yeah, absolutely. Stack Overflow has received [several rounds of investments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/), so it ultimately comes down to the investors' interests.

Comment: Yep, our investors *love* April Fools though. I can't help it, they're just nuts about it. And it's March in a few days, so 55.9 engineers will start working on it soon.

Comment: @JoeBlow You are trying to point out something important, and many people agree with you, so I'd like to understand what you really mean by ***broken***. I never maximize my browser window; I make it just wide enough to make the "idiotic right-hand column" disappear and it works well for me (Windows 7; Chrome browser). I have measured the width of my browser window just to discover what width is best for me; it's 960 pixels (including various window borders). It seems perfectly fine, so I am obviously missing something, which is ***broken*** but unimportant for me. What is it?

Comment: hey, on almost all modern web sites if you reduce your browser width, smaller than including the right hand column, it simply then doesn't include the right hand column.  it's an absolute basic of ordinary reactive design.

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, I use the following user stylesheet to make Stack Overflow and other SE sites work in a narrower window:

```
#sidebar
{ width: 250px !important; }

.topbar .topbar-wrapper,
.footerwrap,
#header,
#content
{ width: 1000px !important; }

.so-header .-container
{ max-width: 1000px; }
```

Comment: I just zoom out to 90%. Stuff breaks, but meh.

Comment: I zoom out to 95% (across the whole internet) and do some similar style changes.  Personally, I think the only reason it doesn't come up more is that those of us who would complain have already figured out how to work around it like this.  Is there any way to get stats on how many have custom stylesheets?

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons I'm user the analytics don't reflect the need for this is that many people that would benefit from it actually have bigger screens. The metrics for my browser right now are going to show 1920x something. That doesn't mean I wouldn't prefer to run this in 1024x  if I could! In fact I very much want to.

I use a tiling window manager and do most of my browsing with two side by side windows open. This means I have about 950px available for each browser. Unfortunately with SE sites not working at this size I have to either load the mobile version or switch to a full screen layout for all SE sites. I do some of both because having to horizontally scroll is just infuriating, but this should really be fixed with some responsive magic so that the sites are useable at any size.

I wouldn't even care if all the content was accessible. Loading the mobile site actually has the advantage of eschewing the sidebar stuff which is great when you're focusing on a task rather than just surfing. A responsive design could just drop whatever doesn't fit.

Comment: You should upgrade [your workplace](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--G-szd85P--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/18ixu6u72efc8jpg.jpg) :P

Comment: Another factor is increasing the text size.I typically have Stack Exchange sites zoomed to at least 130%.

Comment: I have all Stack Exchange sites set to 90% zoom, which my browser remembers. This makes them fit neatly in half a 1920-pixel-wide screen, but it also makes the text a little smaller. That's fine for me, but has accessibility implications for many people.

Comment: @anaximander: ....I just tried this, and I think this might work for me too. It's a bit crazy that \*I\* have to implement the solution myself and that the design isn't responsive, but the font decrease doesn't seem to be that bad. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I typically have the entire web zoomed to 90%

Answer (score 3):

I use a projector at work (being farther from the screen greatly reduces eye strain), and as a result while my resolution is high, the screen width is only 1007px. This causes a horizontal scrollbar which causes all sorts of annoyances to me.

I understand that my screen dimension is not in the "mainstream", and so I fixed this issue for myself a long time ago. I have now made it available at large through a free chrome extension.

You can get it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknarrow/gedamclmheaaaghbopmamikcgdpibikn?hl=en-US

The code (in case you want to port it, don't worry copyleft, i.e. free to do whatever with) is at github: https://github.com/travisjj/StackNarrow

And here is a sample screenshot at a screen width of 1007px:

[image]