# When will we have HTTPS connections throughout Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a *semi*-duplicate of *[https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270602/561731)*, but it has been deferred for ~2 years.

It seems that [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) *is* now supposed to work on Stack Overflow, and it is past the 6-8 weeks of test time for HTTPS.

Do we know when the full rollover to HTTPS on Stack Overflow will be?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it's still deferred. Too much time spent focusing on adding new features of dubious merit. No one likes to pay technical debt.

Comment: It's not possible to give an exact timeframe, but a lot of progress has been made on this in the past few months.

Comment: It doesn't work? It was my understanding that ssl doesn't work on per-site metas (I'm using https/ssl on meta.SO right now, without any issue).

Comment: @Zizouz212 Try to go to `https://www.stackoverflow.com` you will be redirected

Comment: Hmmm... That doesn't work for me, I just use `https://stackoverflow.com` and it doesn't complain.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I know :-)

Comment: Full HTTPS support is expected in [6 - 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

Comment: "Around 6 to 8 weeks"

Comment: I'm pretty sure we will get another April fools game in 2017 before this gets implemented. There are other *important* stuff to be taken care of, you know?

Comment: You cannot be serious @BradWerth ... Read my question...

Comment: I did. It is the same feature, status deferred. When that tag gets removed, it will be in place... I get that it seems like an insane amount of time to implement a very simple thing, but this really boils down to the same exact question. Being it has been literally years, I would put money on Unikong 4 before TLS.

Comment: @BradWerth that Q is a bug report for one...

Comment: I think Adam Lear's answer backs me up... Same thing, status deferred, as you yourself have pointed out.

Comment: @TJ You have a point. If we put every developer in the company on the same project, it'll get done that much faster.

Answer (score 16):

> Do we know when the full rollover to https on Stack Overflow will be?

No, we don't.

I can tell you that it's being worked on (next step: moving meta sites to the *.meta.stackexchange.com URL scheme from meta.*.stackexchange.com), but there is no deadline or ETA. We're solving issues, paying down tech debt as needed, and making progress as time allows amidst everything else that's currently in progress.

Comment: Hmmm why the meta url swap? (curiosity)

Comment: @Neal In short, because we can't get a wildcard cert to cover meta.*.stackexchange.com, and getting 150+ (and counting) individual certs isn't feasible either. More details in Nick's blog post: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: @AdamLear Naive question: is a free automated cert service like https://letsencrypt.org/ a viable solution to the "getting 150+ certs isn't feasible" problem?

Comment: @ThisClark Not in our case - the issue isn't just the provisioning and the cost. Nick goes into the issues with that approach in his post towards the end: search for "We would prefer not to change domains for our content" to jump to the right spot.

Comment: @AdamLear "what happens to our google rank when we start sending everyone to HTTPS, including crawlers? " - it will probably go way up when Google stops penalizing you for not using HTTPS. (Yes I know you didn't write that; it's in response to your link)

Comment: @immibis Eh, that post is now over 3 years old. ;) We aren't hurting for ranking still AFAIK, but yeah, that part of the post probably doesn't apply (as much or at all) anymore.

Comment: I don't see why you need a dedicated IP for every cert, SNI is well supported nowadays (so wildcard certificates or lots of subject alternative names are not really needed) - also Let's Encrypt can easily be used to get lots of certificates w/o problems (or costs)...

Comment: @MrTux which is why Let's Encrypt isn't widely considered trustworthy.

Comment: @Qix Let's Encrypt is widely considered trustworthy: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/which-browsers-and-operating-systems-support-lets-encrypt/4394?u=mrtux

Comment: @MrTux Handing out certificates willy-nilly goes against the whole concept of trust-based cryptography unless they regularly evaluate the people they sign.

Comment: @Qix From my experience most certificates are just domain validated as Let's Encrypt does. - if you are talking about EV certificates, there also hard limits apply (IIRC no wildcards: http://serverfault.com/a/69977).