# Mixed content error on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Tags: bug, ssl

Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m

[image: screenshot of warning message]

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://teststackoverflow.com/?test=ExDNS_2&size=1024'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't fully HTTPS ready.

Comment: Marking my question as a duplicate of a duplicate, this is a dangerous game gents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of August 29 this year, HTTPS still isn't fully supported on Stackexchange.
There is currently no concrete timeline when it will be fully supported.

A word from Adam Lear on this:

> ```
> Do we know when the full rollover to https on Stack Overflow will be?
> ```
>
> No, we don't.
>
> I can tell you that it's being worked on (next step: moving meta sites
>   to the *.meta.stackexchange.com URL scheme from
>   meta.*.stackexchange.com), but there is no deadline or ETA. We're
>   solving issues, paying down tech debt as needed, and making progress
>   as time allows amidst everything else that's currently in progress.

[(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333419/)

Also interesting, a [blog post by Nick Craver in 2014](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) adressing some of the issues SE is still facing with implementing HTTPS/SSL

Comment: I'm sorry but if an resource is loaded from one of the test domains of Stack Overflow I don't think blaming https support is correct in that case. I rather suspect an dev having pushed something on the prod branch that should have kept local. I can't repro this.

Comment: @rene I think its just a remainder of something that was grandfathered in and not considered until recently, due to the low visibility. It means though that if they had done HTTPS usage testing and rolled it out officially, that would have been caught. It may be a bug, but discarding HTTPS its an invisible and barely noticeable one.

Comment: @rene check out http://teststackoverflow.com/ :) *"We are not adding this extra hit to every request, but less than 1% of the requests to our network."*

Comment: In that case, its probably intentional and a side effect of that lack of SSL support truly, then :p

Comment: Fair enough ... ;)