# Is Stack Overflow secure even when not using HTTPS?

Tags: support, security, ssl

I noticed stackoverflow.com doesn't force the use of an HTTPS connection even when the user is logged in.

I've found [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67066/why-is-stackoverflow-not-using-https-for-all-its-page) on security.stackexchange.com on ***"Why is Stack Overflow not using HTTPS for all its pages?"***, but the answer regarding the security of users' information is still vague.

In [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210304/non-https-links-to-other-stackexchange-sites-in-user-profile-when-using-https), it's said that it's a design choice to overcome some mixed content warnings.

I'm sure you wouldn't risk the information of your users to be compromised, and you might be using some sort of JavaScript-based encryption to get around this, but I would like to hear from you guys.

So, is my connection secure when I access SO with HTTP? If it is the case, could you explain how? If it's not, would you let us know if it's in your road map and when would it be supported?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secure"? What type of security are you hoping for? Aside from the login page, virtually all of the information I submit to Stack Overflow is public anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sure you've heard of packet injections. Using https is not an option, it should be mandatory and has not much to do with the data you're posting/getting being private or public.

Comment: Login is always over https so those exchanges are secure.

Comment: I suppose your concern is more about session hijacking than privacy? (Though obviously a hijacked session would mean loss of privacy for any data that is not already public)

Comment: A common response on security.se is "when asking if something is secure, you need to know what attacks you are securing against". The question "is SO secure?" is essentially unanswerable, because there are dozens of ways it is, and possibly dozens of ways it isn't (and maybe can't be). *This would be true even if every page was served over HTTPS.* If you can clarify what kind of security threat you're concerned about, someone may be able to tell you if and how SO protects against it.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin This doesn't answer your question but you may consider using HTTPS Everywhere, a browser extension that forces HTTPS for many sites.

Comment: The NSA could be reading this RIGHT NOW! Oh, wait..

Comment: more updates on this here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images

Comment: Is there a way to force our browser to connect on https for specifics urls ? (Chrome) Specifically targeting to all stackexchange sites ?
I found a related question [http://superuser.com/questions/913469/force-chrome-to-try-https-instead-of-http-when-possible](http://superuser.com/questions/913469/force-chrome-to-try-https-instead-of-http-when-possible).

Comment: @Machavity: "reading" alone is not that problematic. The main issue is that without HTTPS,  it is much more likely that others can read your cookie and then log in as you, and also *modify* the data you are receiving or sending.

Comment: This is a great question, and I also find it quite ironic it isn't serving over HTTPS, since nearly all programmers can agree HTTPS is better, and SO is the de-facto developer central.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, there are a number of things about the http connection that are not secure.

- Your traffic can be sniffed. This means that someone can see what pages you're visiting. This may or may not be a concern for you.

  - I'm not personally concerned about people knowing what stuff about regexes I'm seeing (for example). It's when I look at my profile page that I'm concerned. Or worse, when a moderator accesses personal information.
- It's easy for the plain text of the webpage to be modified. This should be very concerning, as it opens up the doorway to anything ranging from annoying advertising to plain old malware. Several users have had this happen:

  - [Stack Exchange's javascript is malicious](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/126745)
  - [Wonderlandads malware only on Stack Exchange websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290134/323179)
  - [Please support HTTPS by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220541/323179)
- [Cookie theft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69171/323179)

  - [OH NO!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbjqD.png)

---

They're working on https. The most recent step has been images:

> 1. Imgur URLs are converted from HTTP to HTTPS. This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected. This has already shipped, and all the old posts were rebaked. (done)
> 2. Prevent submission of posts that contain HTTP images. Instead of the HTTP image the markdown editor will show an additional error with an option to bring up the image uploading tool with the URL pre-populated, so you can easily upload it to Imgur (we can't do that on your behalf, because cc-by-sa, and whatnot). (done - enabled on mSO and SO)
> 3. After this is enabled, old posts that have HTTP images (~12k on SO), accessible via HTTPS, will be edited according. This will be an actual markdown change, attributed to the Community user, posts won't be bumped. (done on SO - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732/timeline#history_bfdef789-8377-41a3-bd80-86425b19db12))
> 4. Rebake remaining posts with HTTP images, so that images linking to HTTP addresses will become links - most of those are dead anyway (~12k HTTP images w/o HTTPS, 16k dead URLs). This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected, but it'll remove any mixed content even when viewing old revisions.

Please see m0sa's post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343276/6083675) for more information about this change.

The other change that will need to be made is the meta URL style. According to Adam Lear [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333419/6083675):

> I can tell you that it's being worked on (next step: moving meta sites to the *.meta.stackexchange.com URL scheme from meta.*.stackexchange.com), but there is no deadline or ETA. We're solving issues, paying down tech debt as needed, and making progress as time allows amidst everything else that's currently in progress.

Comment: Is there still a need for "moving meta sites to the *.meta.stackexchange.com" with such things as Let's Encrypt?

Comment: @NathanOsman LE SAN certs are limited to 100 Aliases, and it brings down other problems when using a "shared" load balancer, so I assume SE does prefer to use a wildcard to avoid too many renewing problems and/or hitting LE limits.

Answer (score 14):

The best that we know about is that it's still in progress.  [Here's a similar question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/175248) which has some details.

To answer your specific questions...

- [Your login is secured](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202525/175248) through your OpenID provider.
- The data you transmit is ***not*** secured, so anyone that wants to snoop on your Stack Exchange traffic could likely do so.
- [There's a lot of work to do](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) to ensure that Stack Exchange runs in SSL.  TLD sites work fine with it (like https://stackoverflow.com - just don't click many links), but you can get into funky situations with `meta.*` sites (for example:  https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Laurel and Makoto's answers more or less say what I was going to say.

We aren't doing anything special to the inherently not-secure HTTP traffic. However, certain parts of the site are already protected (e.g. authentication/login), and for the most part Stack Overflow will work fine if you were to consciously browse it over HTTPS.

There's still work to be done before we can force everyone to it, however. That work *is* happening. The devil's in the details of decisions made in the past (like the URL scheme for meta sites) and user-contributed content.

As far as I know at the moment, we're about to deploy forcing all uploaded images to go over HTTPS, and the start of the Great Meta Shuffle of 2017 is coming shortly as well. (That's where we move child metas to a URL pattern we can actually cover with an SSL certificate without having to provision a new one for each site we have and each site we launch in the future.)

In the meantime, we don't officially support it (and it most notably doesn't work if you're trying to log into [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)), but an addon like HTTPS Everywhere should help you out with not having to worry about whether you're hitting HTTP or HTTPS Stack Overflow.

Comment: All uploaded images are currently served over HTTPS AFAICT.

Comment: @TinyGiant Oh yeah, new ones should be. We still need to do a backfill to bring up previously uploaded images (from other providers? I'm hazy on specifics here) in line as well. m0sa's working on that, so he might chime in to tell me all the details I got wrong. :)

Comment: This pretty much sums it up. We're working hard on solving the last mixed-content and meta issues (which have so, so many caveats and edge cases we found along the way, since my 2013 post). The hope is have HTTPS valid on **all** Stack Overflow pages within the next month (99.999% are already fine), and all network sites shortly after that. The next step is making it default/canonical which we'll do as soon as we possibly can. There are ugly realities at every turn. The follow-up blog post will be oh so very long. My wife/editor may kill me after being asked to review it.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, images uploaded to imgur used to be returned as http, so I'm guessing this would just be updating the database to replace all `http://i.stack.imgur` with `https://i.stack.imgur`

Comment: @TinyGiant Unfortunately, that's the easy case :) The problem comes in with the many thousands of *other* domains people used for their images over the years. After all you don't *have* to upload to us, you could put an image link directly in the markdown, and with tens of millions of posts that happened. On some sites, frequently. So we have to https:// those (if supported), or change them into links if not (very non-trivial). That's one example of user content crazy we have to deal with along the way.

Comment: @Nick I realize that, I was mostly confused by *"we're about to deploy forcing all uploaded images to go over HTTPS"*, because currently any image uploaded to Stack Overflow will be served over HTTPS. This point was clarified by Adam's first comment. My last comment was to make sure I understood that correctly. I'm sure that figuring out which external images *can* be served over HTTPS is a feat all on its own.

Comment: "the Great Meta Shuffle of 2017" .. why does this make me think of a lot of elderly people dancing in a retirement home?

Comment: @TimPost - they are all probably shuffling around looking for their lost keys.