# HTTPS-only images

Tags: discussion, images, ssl

#### UPDATE

This is now enabled network-wide, more info on mSE:

[Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/156631)

---

As you might've heard, we're working really hard on rolling out HTTPS support on our sites. One of the biggest blockers is mixed content. In the next 6-8 weeks, we'll be rolling out some changes to alleviate this issue on the first page load, namely:

1. Imgur URLs are converted from HTTP to HTTPS. This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected. This has already shipped, and all the old posts were rebaked. (done)
2. Prevent submission of posts that contain HTTP images. Instead of the HTTP image the markdown editor will show an additional error... 
   [image: additional error]
   ... with an option to bring up the image uploading tool with the URL pre-populated, so you can easily upload it to Imgur (we can't do that on your behalf, because cc-by-sa, and whatnot):
   [image: image uploaded - pre-populated with url]
   (done - enabled on mSO and SO)
3. After this is enabled, old posts that have HTTP images (~12k on SO), accessible via HTTPS, will be edited accordingly. This will be an actual markdown change, attributed to the Community user, posts won't be bumped. (done - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732/timeline#history_bfdef789-8377-41a3-bd80-86425b19db12))
4. Rebake remaining posts with HTTP images, so that images linking to HTTP addresses will become links - most of those are dead anyway (~12k HTTP images w/o HTTPS, 16k dead URLs). This will be a HTML baking change, so no Markdown will be affected, but it'll remove any mixed content even when viewing old revisions. (done)

Behold, lists of all affected [SO](http://pastebin.com/TvWdaFq1) and [Meta SO](http://pastebin.com/VJKuQUNN) post ids.

Comment: Why here and not on MSE? Is it for Stack Overflow only?

Comment: @Oded will the announcement that the announcement tag is now available be its first use? :p

Comment: @ShadowWizard SO is our #1 priority, so we're gonna start here, for others sites and their metas we still need to do the `meta.*.se.com` -> `*.meta.se.com` migration before doing this

Comment: @m0sa I see what you did there with the [image link](http://i41.tinypic.com/2q155pk.jpg) you put in the screenshot.

Comment: #3 http -> https url replace for known good URLs is in progress -> [example history entry](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732/timeline#history_bfdef789-8377-41a3-bd80-86425b19db12)

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55061/can-malware-be-attached-to-an-image

Comment: @m0sa Why the need for the switch in meta addresses?  I keep noticing it be mentioned, but I'm unsure of the technical reason for doing so? (edit) - just noticed that wildcard certs only cover 1 level deep - I assume this is the reasoning?

Comment: @JamesThorpe https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: url replace done on SO

Comment: So you only need to do #4 then you can enable https by default on SO?

Comment: @TinyGiant - no. There are a lot of other things still in play. This is a big step in getting there.

Comment: I noticed that in [the example edit you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4732/revisions) an image link seemingly got replaced with an embeded image by the edit. Is that intended? Edit: Nevermind, it seems that was just the result of change #4.

Comment: @Ajedi32 that's because #3 ob the post and #4 when rendering the old  revision's markdown (we don't store html of old revisions)..  In the previous revision it was an http image, check the markdown diff

Comment: "16k dead URLs": can you automatically replace these by archive.org mirrored ones?

Comment: @Knu no, since they are hosted on domains not captured by archive.org, and broken there as well, e.g. [example](http://web.archive.org/web/20100804211921/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85866/c-component-do-not-refresh-when-source-code-updated)

Comment: @m0sa Id be damned if a majority of those images weren't captured by archive.org. The goal is to save what can be.

Comment: _"with an option to bring up the image uploading tool with the URL pre-populated, so you can easily upload it to Imgur "_ That's nice.

Comment: The thing with uploading to imgur usually doesn't work. It gives an error message saying "this format is not supported". So when a user with less than 10 reputation posts a link to an HTTP image and I want to change the link to an image, I have to download the image onto my computer to upload it. That's quite annoying.

Comment: @DonaldDuck can you elaborate please? users shouldn't be able to write posts with http images anymore.. are you looking at old posts?

Comment: @m0sa New users who don't have enough reputation to post images insert plain links to images on HTTP sites. Say they use the markdown `[image](http://example.com/example.png)`. Then I try to convert this link to an image by adding `!` in front of it giving `![image](http://example.com/example.png)`. Since it's HTTP, the image is replaced with the error message that you mentioned in your post. So I click the link "Upload to imgur", it automatically puts the URL in the "Link from the web" text input box, then I click Add Picture and that's when I often get "this format is not supported".

Comment: How do I find old posts of mine that contain http images? What do I search for?

Comment: @MrLister you can use the list of all [affected SO posts](http://pastebin.com/TvWdaFq1) linked above for cross-referencing it with your posts in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: https://imgur.com/  has blocked incoming traffic from Iran.

Answer (score 38):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Update the Flair HTML snippet

---

Can you please update the HTML snippet in the **Flair** section with **https** in the `<img src="http://`.

Since copy & paste the snippet to the About me section, it shows the warning as showed in the #2.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Flair HTML Snippet without https]

Comment: that would break meta.*.se.com pages,  so we'll do it after the domain shuffle

Comment: @m0sa: Oh, Okay.

Comment: FWIW, 3 developers thought this was safe to change. I was the first. It's been fixed 3 times...and reverted 3 times :) As soon as it's valid on child SE metas and their URL rendering kicks over, so shall the flair.

Answer (score 4):

> Prevent submission of posts that contain HTTP images. […]
>   [In] remaining posts with HTTP images [that are not HTTPS-accessible] no Markdown will be affected.

Wait, does that mean when I'm trying to edit an old post that has an old image link (i.e. was not edited by Community), I cannot submit without also fixing the image?
Not that it'll likely happen often, but it would be very annoying. Just as [Edit to an old question cannot be saved because title too long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305959/1048572).

Comment: No. As pointed out in the question, we're changing all old images to either the HTTPS version or to a standard link that isn't an image, if no HTTPS version is available. Editing is not required.

Comment: @animuson I understood that this replacement by a standard link happens in the HTML baker only, so when I click the edit button on such a post it will load markdown that still contains the HTTP image inclusion?

Comment: @Bergi you understood correctly. We have everything in place, so that we could enable submission of posts with HTTP images after the rebake processor for #4 is enabled. We choose not to, initially, since we found that the behavior might be surprising for new users (as in, "where is my image?! my markdown is correct!"), if they missed the #2 error (which would become a warning in that case) in the preview...

Comment: ha, I have to correct myself, @animuson was right...

Answer (score -11):

Please ensure that images will still be accessible via HTTP after this is rolled out. I frequently use SO at work where I am behind a corporate firewall that has to track and audit what we see. Because of that most (but not all) HTTPS sites are blocked, and that includes imgur.

Comment: imgur images have been rendered as https on new posts since last month,  so...

Comment: @m0sa Yeah, I noticed. I end up pasting the image address into a new taband taking the `s` out. It's not fun, but it's what I'm stuck with. I just want to ensure I'll still be able to do that.

Comment: after #4 you'll even have a link to the HTTP image, for non HTTPS images. Although, after we go full HTTPS, HTTPS links will become canonical, and you'll land on `https://stackoverflow.com` when clicking on search engine result links...

Comment: I think I'll be ok in that case because SO is already whitelisted for HTTPS blocking (IE im able to login at work), just not imgur. If the HTTPS migration breaks SO at my work I'm sure my bosses will quickly find a solution when productivity suddenly plummets :).

Comment: *where I am behind a corporate firewall that has to track and audit what we see.* => Oh, I thought the solution to that was for corporations to perform a MITM by installing their own omnipotent certificate on all their computers. Of course it voids any guarantee of privacy for the users, but that's what track/audit is about. You may or may not want to suggest that to your company...

Comment: Would it be possible to add a link to the image, pointing to the original non-HTTPS image?

Comment: _"Because of that most (but not all) HTTPS sites are blocked, and that includes imgur."_ You're going to have substantial problems using most of the web before too long, even if your company pins you to old browser versions (which they'll have to do). Either that, or a massive whitelist :) I concur with Matthieu.

Comment: You might want to suggest to your company that they add the subdomain `stack.imgur.com` (or specifically the hostname `i.stack.imgur.com`) to the whitelist. AFAIK, it's only used by the Stack Exchange image uploader.