# Why is "Meta" in the beginning of Meta SO when it is in the end of other Meta SE Communities?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that we have [**Meta** Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the word Meta is on the begining of the name.

For other Meta SE Communities, the word Meta is at the end of their names.

[image: Meta SO]

Is there a reason for naming this perticular Meta SE with the word "Meta" in the beginning?

Comment: Purely historical reasons, I think - Meta SO was there first, and was just named that way. For the sites that came later, it was presumably decided that "... Meta" sounds better.

Comment: IIRC, even SU and SF have Meta at the start.

Comment: We also have Meta Stack Exchange, and that one is relatively new.

Comment: [naming things is hard](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096) ...

Comment: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesman and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do. He may as well concern himself with his shadow on the wall. Speak what you think now in hard words, and to-morrow speak what to-morrow thinks in hard words again, though it contradict every thing you said to-day." - Ralph Waldo Emerson

Comment: Glancing up, can't help but point out that "meta" is at the end at the top of the page I'm looking at right now... (at left end of top bar)

Comment: SO got its meta in an usual way.  Started in 2008, it didn't its meta until 2014.  By then the acronyms MSE and MSO were already boilerplate in any discussion about it, took quite a while before it was implemented.  So it didn't get to be SOM, they kept MSO.

Comment: @BobJarvis Remind me never to vote you into public office. You'd be a terrifyingly good politician.

Comment: This is one of those "I've been using SO for _years_ and I never noticed this" moments

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to the Meta Meta?

Comment: @MrLister feel free to do so if you think it would fit.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the domain names of each site will match that ordering pretty soon. meta.scifi.stackexchange.com will become scifi.meta.stackexchange.com, meta.gaming.stackexchange.com will become gaming.meta.stackexchange.com, etc, while meta.stackoverflow.com will remain the same: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images#comment444534_343276

Comment: I bet this would create much confusion if you had e.g. [Meta Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/) (compare to [Metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably left over as a result of how Meta progressed (this is off the top of my head since finding dates for this stuff is hard)

1. SO launches
2. [Meta.SO launches](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/) to talk about how/why SO should do things
3. SO changes name to Stack Exchange
4. Meta.SO becomes Meta.SE for the network in general (and is the only Meta where reputation is earned/lost)
5. Every community gets their own Meta, including a new Meta.SO

So why is it Meta.SO and Meta.SE? Because of the URL. This is a subdomain of SO and people started calling it by its URL. Meta.SE inherited its name (and subdomain) from Meta.SO. But the new site metas became

```
 meta.[site].stackexchange.com
```

So you get some crazy long URLs like

```
meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com
```

And since those metas belong to the communities they serve, it makes sense to call them `[site] Meta` instead of `Meta [site]`. It also means you can sort the list alphabetically.

Comment: All communities had their own Meta long before MSE was a thing. I'd like to say they've always had their own Meta, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: This answer all boils down to _"And since those metas belong to the communities they serve, it makes sense to call them [site] Meta instead of Meta [site]"_, which isn't very convincing IMO. Although the sorting thing makes some sense, depending on what constraints there are on site lists.

Comment: Yup, same reason we have abbreviations "pt.SO", "ru.SO", "stats.SE", etc.