# HTTPS: It's time

Tags: discussion, ssl, announcement

**Update:** The network move has started, you can follow here: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

---

This is a heads up, and a request for help.

HTTPS for our entire network is [long overdue](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), but we've been working hard on it behind the scenes. Expect a pretty big blog post when we turn it on everywhere that details the journey.

There are a few lingering questions on HTTPS we're not confident in until we do it live. One of these is the Google site move in webmasters. It *still* (to our disbelief) treats HTTP and HTTPS as different properties. I have no idea why. And the "change of address" tool [doesn't support such a move either](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en):

> **Note:** The tool does not currently support the following kinds of site moves: subdomain name changes, protocol changes (from HTTP to HTTPS), or path-only changes.

So we'll have to create [property sets](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/tie-your-sites-together-with-property.html) for *every single site* during the move to HTTPS. Fun!

Given the above, we need to see how all of this works in practice with real load:
**We're starting with [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)**.

Here's an order of things that's been going on:

1. <kbd>done</kbd> Infrastructure in place:

   - A fast CDN/Proxy for local termination (Fastly)
   - Certificates (including IP pooling support to bridge HTTP/1.1 & HTTP/2)
   - Logging
2. <kbd>done</kbd> Get third-party support in place:

   - All per-site scripts onto our CDN and served securely
   - Ad providers to HTTPS
3. <kbd>done</kbd> Fix a ton of code that assumes `http://` in a million places.
4. <kbd>done</kbd> Prevent users from embedding new `http://` content (e.g. [forcing HTTPS images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images)).
5. <kbd>done</kbd> Cleanup all existing user content that was `http://` (`https://` where possible, and converted to links if we can't embed it securely).
6. <kbd>done</kbd> Make sites render absolute URLs as `https://`.
7. <kbd>done</kbd> Move canonical URLs to `https://`.
8. <kbd>done</kbd> 302 Traffic to `https://` for search engines.
9. <kbd>done</kbd> 301 Traffic to `https://` for search engines.
10. <kbd>done</kbd> 301 Traffic to `https://` for all.
11. <kbd>done</kbd> **(Child metas)** Move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`.
12. Force all Q&A traffic to `https://` (and set an https-only cookie)
13. Migrate all existing sessions to secure sessions (this will take time to run).
14. Use HSTS to ensure browsers don't hit Q&A sites via `http://` at all.

This is a really high level list, there are a crazy number of nuances and edge cases to the above. This is for Q&A. Area 51, Chat, and [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) (the main site) have a separate set of concerns and code we'll address after Q&A. The list also isn't necessarily in order. While we're testing #6, [Samo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) and I will be working on #11 at the same time.

We want your help simply reporting any issues here with insecure content on `https://` or any other oddities you see. We'll try to address them as soon as possible.

Comment: Yay! Congratulations! Naturally, 1st priority is to make sure the [`<kbd>` castle question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) works ok and without edge cases. Everything else can wait. Checking now. (Edit: all is well.)

Comment: Great job @Nick, the [road to SSL](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) was certainly a hard one!

Comment: Should this be [meta-tag:featured] perhaps?

Comment: Shouldn't this really be on MSE?

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope - it's not affecting SO yet. When we leave the test realm on this site it'll appear on MSE as featured.

Comment: @Cai nope - it **only** affects MSO right now. Once we shake out any issues here, then we'll begin MSE and network-wide moves.

Comment: @Nick ok, thanks for the clarification (that isn't very clear in the post, and some of that list talks about site*s*)

Comment: Given that you mention changing the url of the child meta as part of the process I really think you should move this to MSE.

Comment: @NickCraver Even if it only affects MSO *right now*, are you going to post on MSE once it affects everyone else?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, we know this will *eventually* affect the whole network, and this will be announced on MSE once we are done testing here on MSO. For now, this only affects MSO where it is being tested.

Comment: @animuson I understand that it's only being tested on MSO, but the post makes reference to MSE and other sites in the network so I thought that posting on MSE would be matter of courtesy if nothing else.

Comment: I can confirm the "webmasters fun", just having done a similar move for a couple of my sites not that long ago. `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are indeed treated as different sites, unfortunately – which makes it a bit weird while "in transition". Thanks to HSTS, not for too long, though :)

Comment: @ChrisF As long as someone posts on MSE before the network-wide change goes live, I'm happy. This can stay here while it only affects SO/MSO, and can either be migrated or a separate post can be made when it starts affecting more things.

Comment: @Seth yes, there will be a different MSE post when it's time.

Comment: `*.meta.stackexchange.com` I'm going to be struggling with this for quite some time, I fear...

Comment: @Will can you elaborate there? We'll have redirects in place of course.

Comment: More out of curiosity than anything else, what's the technical reason for the child meta name flipperoo? I assume it's something to do with your certificates?

Comment: I usually get to meta by typing "met" and either accepting the first URL that appears in the address bar (meta.stackexchange.com) or I hit the down arrow and then hit enter (meta.stackoverflow.com).  I'll have to retrain myself now :/  ...  unless you're going to have a redirect that will still work for me in this scenario...

Comment: I thought that the blogs were shut down?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Wildcards only work on the leftmost subdomain, so meta.*.stackexchange.com is not possible, and provisioning 160-odd sites across 320-odd domains, with no more than 100 sites per certificate, did not seem to the team like a fun project.

Comment: How do you implement the 302/301 redirects *for search engines only*? Isn’t this frowned upon / might search engines not detect this as [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking)?

Comment: @unor: Since the content is the same after the redirect, I doubt it.

Comment: Have you folks considered using `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header to check in advance what resources are still being loaded over HTTP, before forcing redirects to HTTPS? It's really cool that you can use CSP in "report-only" mode like this, and I have yet to hear of a large company use this functionality.

Comment: @Will If you're using a smart enough browser, that should still work, even once the only URL in your history is stackoverflow.meta... rather than meta.stackoverflow... because the "meta" is still there, and "frecency" will still bubble it to the top. I've generally found Firefox's autocomplete to be smarter than Chrome's, but it's a long time since I've used Chrome enough to build up a history, so I may be out of date on that.

Comment: @Flimm we're using some other methods there. Our client timings we're collecting *anyway* are reporting `http://` loads for most things. But we're also keeping an overall eye on it. It's a question of how many extra requests we're comfortable with for a move.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out a mixed content warning on chat. I think that POST requests are the trigger since there's no warning before the POST requests are fired, but the request is done over https, so I don't know.

Comment: Just noticed today when i logged in my session was out, and few minutes back now noticed written secure in address bar, searched instantly on meta and found this. kudos to all who made this happen finally!!

Comment: @Braiam Chat isn't mixed-content free...that'll take a lot of thinking but is next on our list after the sites. That has a different set of user-content concerns by its realtime nature, unfortunately. There are some problems with embeds and one-boxes we need to think through there.

Comment: Firefox reports "Your connection is not secure" opening [this `.stackexchange.com` link](https://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1299) - "The owner of ... has configured their web site improperly"

Comment: This seems to be a good idea -- but will it break any existing bookmarks?

Answer (score 24):

For tracking purposes, so people can see at a quick glance:

#### Running list of fixed items (please keep reporting!):

1. Network-wide flair
2. Site switcher dropdown
3. Share URLs were `http://` (in build `2017.3.6.25308`)

#### Known issues

1. Footer links are relative (this has been the case for some time...we're deciding what to do there due to caching constraints)
2. The Child-Meta move has resulted in a bug with HTTPS-Everywhere, resulting in `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Either temporarily disable HTTPS-Everywhere or wait for the [fix to be merged](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110) and released upstream

Comment: I'm looking at this page's source, and there are a few `http` links: the `<head>` metadata `twitter:app:url:googleplay` and `og:url` links, canonical URL, and the sidebar "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts". All of these sort of make sense, so maybe it's intentional.

Comment: Found a minor one: the user settings > connected applications page (for me https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/apps/7586 ) has an http winter bash logo (!?): http://i.stack.imgur.com/sRnbB.png

Comment: The RSS feed has been acting hinkey lately, with double entries (at least within my feed reader).  Not all of them, but I'm getting dupe links with one being http and the other https.  Not sure if it's the fault of the reader or the feed.

Comment: @Kobi do you mean the icon in the top bar of your browser? Not for me.

Comment: @riker no they are talking about the `<head>` element in the HTML itself.

Comment: Serious problem: Apparently images are being enforced to have HTTPS. This is a problem for flairs, as the main sites seem to support HTTPS but the meta's don't.  [Here, when both images are http only](http://imgur.com/a/pwc1j), and when [https on both](http://imgur.com/a/m2wFX). As you can see, the main site flair works but  the meta doesn't.

Comment: @Riker - yep, that's correct. We won't have working HTTPS flair on child metas until the domain move. We're working on that now, but it's not a new situation. HTTPS content has *never* worked on child metas...so we're fixing quite a wide range of things here.

Comment: Another weird RSS hiccough... All my RSS feeds came with the same batch of perl questions https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZJVU.png the original questions never had the tags, it appears.  The image is for EnvDTE, here's one from the list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644082/perl-finding-maximum-then-divide-by-the-max-value-by-comparing-value-vs-by-arr Checking the RSS feed now I don't see any of these questions in there, so it appears it might have been a temporary issue.  Wanted to report it anyhow (not worth a question on its own)

Comment: The footer links being relative shouldn't matter, right? I mean, if the whole network gets switched to HTTPS then those links will also be always on an HTTPS page and thus link to the HTTPS version

Comment: I just noticed that the “Possible duplicate” auto-comments are still linking with `http`.

Comment: I noticed that the links in Hot Network Questions that redirect to the site don't include the "https://" (`stackoverflow.com/...` instead of `https://stackoverflow.com/...`).

Answer (score -5):

**(Child metas)** Move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`.

This is a *terrible* idea! Here's why.

Say there's the site `waffles.stackexchange.com`. Waffles SE. Now, just like any other site in the StackExchange network, Waffles SE has Meta Waffles SE.

*Meta Waffles SE is part of Waffles SE. Therefore, its URL will be `meta.waffles.stackexchange.com`.*
 `meta.waffles.stackexchange.com` implies that you're on the Meta subdomain of Waffles.

Now say we move it to `waffles.meta.stackexchange.com`. Whoa, what? Meta SE is its own thing - its own site! Waffles isn't part of Meta SE!

`meta.waffles.stackexchange.com` implies Meta of Waffles of StackExchange.

`waffles.meta.stackexchange.com` implies Waffles of meta of StackExchange.

Please, don't change it to something that makes no sense! Don't mess with a constant part of StackExchange! People who've been around the network for a while are *not* going to like this - no one will want to adjust to this change.

Comment: No downvote, but I do wish you'd used 'cheese' instead of 'waffles' for your example. :)

Comment: Child metas are being moved from meta.sitename.SE to sitename.meta.SE because browsers don't accept TLS certificates with the scope `meta.*.stackexchange.com` (or any other certificate for any domain name that has a wildcard in the middle). Also, people not wanting to change can be easily solved by redirecting all meta.sitename.SE traffic to sitename.meta.SE.

Comment: @dorukayhan: But why do we need TLS certificates with the scope `meta.*.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @ruakh Because `meta.*.stackexchange.com` is for some reason not a subset of `*.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @dorukayhan: Ah, right. (I think that behavior is actually browser-dependent -- but of course we want a solution that does *not* depend on the browser.) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, there's a RFC for it https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818: Names may contain the wildcard
   character \* which is considered to match any single domain name
   component or component fragment. E.g., \*.a.com matches foo.a.com but
   not bar.foo.a.com. f\*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

Comment: [Nick Craver's personal blogpost](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) on this *very* issue - which is linked in the main question anyway - is the ***best*** primer to this subject.  It explains clearly why the switch is needed, in spite of your objections to the name changes.

Comment: The comments are correct here - see my blog post for details. The jerk who bought `*.*.com` and ruined it for everybody means we have no other real options here without tremendous complication on many fronts - and greatly increased cost. It also eliminated IP pooling possibilities, which let us keep HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 optimized across domains at the same time. Redirects were always the plan, and are automatically in place due to how we do the move. Example: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com

Comment: While semantically he's correct, it does seem as though internet limitations may prevent continuation of the old method from being feasible.