# Why are child meta links flipped after transition to HTTPS?

Tags: support, ssl

As seen from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time), Stack Exchange network is transiting to the HTTPS protocol.

In the list of things to be done, one item caught my attention:

> 11. **(Child metas)** Move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`.

So, from what I understand:

- https://meta.site.stackexchange.com will be changed to https://site.meta.stackexchange.com.

Just curious, why is this change needed?

Comment: RFC <some number> disallows having meta.*.stackexchange.com kinda URLs in the SSL cert.

Comment: @BhargavRao: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3 specifically

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Nick Craver explains in his [intro blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) from a few years back, `meta.*.stackexchange.com` is not a valid wildcard certificate. And the upkeep of managing 166 sites, plus 164 child meta sites, all listed exhaustively and spread across certificates in groups of 100 per certificate (the maximum number of domains anyone will issue in a single certificate, and each certificate needing a separate IP address), is not something SE wanted to deal with. (Especially given private beta launches every so often.)

So that doesn't really leave many options.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much this. One `*.meta.stackexchange.com` certificate, vs 166 certificates (and more added every week).

Comment: Ultimately, it's because some jerk bought `*.*.com` decades ago. So they pretty much ruined it for everybody.

Comment: Doesn't the existence of automated CAs like Let's Encrypt makes this less of an issue, since you could just have a new cert automatically issued every time a new site is created (with no manual action required)?

Comment: @Ajedi32 but are they automagically renewed?

Comment: @Pureferret: LE does auto-renew by default, and has a correspondingly short expiration time (90 days).

Comment: @NickCraver - why wouldn't ``*.*.stackoverflow.com`` work, assuming your example does?

Comment: @shadow: Because the specs and implementations were changed to prevent that sort of exploit happening again.

Comment: I didn't release that was an exploit, though it makes sense now that you point that out. It's a pain to google that - do you have a link to information about what exactly happened?

Comment: Why not just use certificates signed by a custom root CA and tell everyone to add it to their trust store? _(Ducks)_

Comment: @NathanOsman: Seems legit, I'll just go tell CAcert how widely successful they've secretly been all this time, shall I?

Comment: @shadow: The RFC in which this change was formalized is linked in the blog post -- https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3. Other than that, I expect looking through the IETF mailing lists during the discussion of that RFC would be as enlightening as anything.

Comment: This bothers me because IMO the `*.meta.stackexchange.com` doesn't make logical/semantic sense considering how the sites actually relate to each other.

Comment: So now you have a `*.stackexchange.com` and a `*.meta.stackexchange.com` and it saves you from adding any new certificate for new children?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's a fairly minor glitch from my perspective, although I do see what you're saying. The difference between "the Space Exploration part of the meta-space" and "the meta site for Space Exploration" is *there*, but still pretty small.

Comment: The "each certificate needing a separate IP" excuse died in April 2014 when extended support for Internet Explorer on Windows XP ended. By that time, IE/XP was the only major browser not to support [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI).

Comment: @DamianYerrick: Apparently, they're still having trouble with Android, although I don't know the details. (E.g. http://disq.us/p/15x94qc)

Comment: What about *.stackexchange.com/meta, or is that worse?

Comment: @AlexWiese: Worse. Messes with all kinds of URL routing. Comments section of that post mentions it and all its myriad problems.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Because SSL isn't only about encryption, it's also about trust. Let's Encrypt allows any and all sites to sign up. When you buy expensive certificates, they're most likely going to vet you as a website. That's why Verisign certificates were (are?) thousands of dollars at one point.

Comment: @Qix: Meh, DV == DV. EV/OV are more expensive, but DV certs are all pretty similar beyond the basic "is the issuing org capable of keeping certs safe?"

Comment: @Qix Let's Encrypt is trusted by all major web browsers. You can't get any more trusted than that as far as CAs go. StackOverflow is only using DV certs, so there's no reason they _couldn't_ go with Let's Encrypt. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/q/13453/29865

Comment: @Ajedi32 I disagree - there are several individuals in the infosec community that validate certificates in their own way. Let's Encrypt is a convenience. But meh, if it's only a DV cert, then it should be okay.

Comment: @Ajedi32: By the way, the fundamental reason LE is not an option for SE is the same as just using a regular paid cert with up to 100 sites per cert: it still requires IP address shuffling, because SNI is not an option.