# Suggested edit queue is full

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Link to edit post below every post on Stack Overflow is disabled for me with a tooltip saying "Suggested edit queue is full".

> [image: full]

Currently there are only 135 edits in queue:

> [image: 135]

I'm not sure if this is the limit. So what is happening here?

For meta posts I see another text:

> [image: meta]

Comment: Probably just caching. It says 180 when I look there.

Comment: @S.L.Barth is 180 a limit?

Comment: I thought the limit was 150 actually. Maybe it's changed again; possibly to accomodate extra edits for the HTTP -> HTTPS switch.

Comment: It's 200 on SO.

Comment: @S.L.Barth You would think that employees would not have to suggest edits for the HTTP -> HTTPS switch...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The user base was [asked to help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345012/812149). I guess they felt automated substitution was too risky (inadvertently changing questions, introducing dead links....).

Comment: @S.L.Barth I didn't see anything in that post asking for help editing anything, just help reporting issues. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan My bad; that is a sister post to [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/168333) on MSE. Over there, there was a request to update image links. I've seen a number of HTTP -> HTTPS converting edits in the queue over there.

Comment: Why the heck is there even a limit on this queue?

Comment: @TylerH Pending edits prevent anyone else from editing the post until they're resolved.  That creates a rather large cost to having tons of pending suggested edits sitting around for an extended period of time.

Comment: @Servy I'm aware that pending edit preventing others from editing, but I'm not sure how the pending edit architecture is relevant to a limit on the number of items allowable in the suggested edits review queue. What does it matter whether there are 200 suggested edits awaiting approval or 2000? More items in the suggested edit review queue does not mean that users can't suggest edits as well on other items. That seems to be making the assumption that only 200 specific posts are worth editing at any time, which is a bad assumption, IMO.

Comment: @TylerH Having a longer and longer queue means suggested edits pending approval for longer and longer, which means greater periods of time where a post can't be edited.  If you let 20,000 edits be pending at a time, then it could take days for a given item to get approved or rejected, preventing other edits to that post for *days* at a time, rather than just for a few minutes.  The assumption is not that there would never be more than 200 posts at a time worth suggesting edits to, rather, the assumption is, if there are already lots of items in the queue the reviewers can't handle more.

Comment: @Servy Does every queue have a limit? That assumption would apply equally to any queue, so if that's the case then there should be.

Comment: @TylerH How does that apply to any other queue?  Nobody is prevented from doing anything on a post just because there's a close vote on it, or because it's being triaged, or because it was flagged as low quality, etc.  The suggested edit queue is the only queue that restricts actions on a post until the review is handled, so it's the only one that needs a limit to prevent items from sitting in the queue for a long time.

Comment: @Servy I was referring to the logic of "the limitation is there because, if there are already lots of items in the queue the reviewers can't handle more".

Comment: @TylerH If there are lots of items in the queue then it means that the reviewers can't handle the items *promptly* anymore.  In every other queue that doesn't matter; it's okay for the reviews to not be prompt.  For suggested edits it's not.

Comment: Currently shows the edit queue is full, when there's 92 listed.  I'm done trying to improve first posts and things, because every time I do, I can't ever send my edits in -- So forget it, helping new posters isn't worth my time anymore, they are just going to have to do it right themselves.

Comment: Here we go, stuck again unable to fix dangerous answers.

Comment: Why a suggested edit __isn't first__ a suggested edit from one  _Stackoverflow_ member to a poster? Why is it mandatory to put a reviewer in the middle when the poster could first accept that suggested change directly, during the next hour, instead ? When I suggest a poster to add a `Python` tag to his post, why is it needed to engage all the reputed members of _Stackoverflow_ in a review?

Comment: Well, this happens every time I try to edit something and I have 143 rep, so...

Comment: The argument that it would take longer for edits to be reviewed feels weird. So now, instead of waiting longer, some edits (at random) are made impossible. How is that better? Isn’t later better that never?

Comment: @servy I also get this tooltip "Suggested edit queue is full" everytime - how can you review your own edit queue? I'm afraid that some of my suggestions will never be reviewed and don't like being unable to edit at all. Please help.

Comment: @Servy Why does a post need to be locked if there's a pending edit? Further edits could be allowed too, and the reviewer could pick the most relevant one or merge them into one, giving credit to both editors. If someone proposes an edit because of a typo, that blocks other users that might want to make much more important edits. Is it that important to resolve edits quickly at the cost of prohibiting *any* other edits?

Comment: @undefined If you want to propose a new feature request to allow people to suggest edits on posts with pending suggested edits you should be making a new post rather than posting it as a comment to this support question.

Comment: In all the 5 years I have being a member, this is the first time I see, almost for two months, the message Suggested edit queue is full. Is there a problem? Who may I ask to check it out? Is there somewhere that shows the current state of the queue? Is there a way that I can help to reduce the number of edits in the queue?

Comment: It'd be great if we would be allowed to see the number of items in that queue. Tried posting a new edit about PII information shared on a GCP question and I get the 'the edit queue is full, check in a few minutes' message.

Comment: Should we make this a faq-proposed question? I think this should be part of the faq questions.

Comment: what i dont get especially is that there are 4+ year old questions that are marked as 'needs to be more focused' with several thousand views but still no one cares enough to look into that for once - also can you somehow see the edit suggestions even if not actively set yet?

Comment: The edit queue needs to be removed, it makes you entirely incapable of editing ever again if enough of your edits are never looked at, and there's nothing you can do about it until you reach 2k rep, which will be a little harder to do now that you are unable to edit.

Comment: @acarlstein indeed, the only LUCK you get prompted to the `/edit` you don't have enough time (maybe less than 1min) to even make edits and avoid making mistakes of your own (*while rushing*):->finalizing the edit (which took you *ABOVE 1 min*) and clicking the `edit` button: **The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!**. And about your question of "is there a way to check the current state of queue"->like @Robert said, you need 2K rep, and unless you are lucky enough for one of your answers to become Top 5 results of the *Holy Google* you ain't reaching it in 100answrs

Comment: This has become like eBay.  What am I supposed to do?  Repeatedly click 'Save Edits' until there happens to be a spare slot in the queue, or set up a bot to do that for me?

Comment: I'm trying to edit a post whose answer does not seems correct and StackOverflow is constantly saying that the edit queue is full. We are taking up time and effort to correct the answers and in the end, find that we just can't submit the edit because there is something called an edit queue, that is disappointing and it discourages others not only from editing the answer but also thinking about correcting the answers. Having a very limiting queue with such a massive amount of content and users doesn't make sense. An author of the post should also be able to accept the edit to their post.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

[As of June 29th, 2017, the suggested edit queue size has increased from 200 to 500.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351728/2415822)

**Original answer:**

[The suggested edit queue has a fixed size,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84362/242209) which is currently 200 for Stack Overflow.  You see 135 probably due to caching.

Go encourage 2k+ users to start reviewing edits in the queue.

Comment: Obligatory: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/.

Comment: @JAL I'd like to encourage you to start reviewing the edit queue. (1 down.....)

Comment: Give me a repeating badge after 1000 edits, and I am encouraged :P

Comment: I'll help if it gives me a gold badge called "useful idiot" after each 1000 reviews. Seems more appropriate than "steward".

Comment: Well, I guess having the review queue gummed up is one way to get rid of robo-reviewers...

Comment: i think this limit makes no sense - some useful edits are lost, because this demotivating reviewers. for now i have a tab list open of 10 edits because of this and waiting for a empty queue :(

Comment: @JAL, How can we resolve this caching issue ? Because I am still facing the same issue right now, that Suggested Edit Queue is Full while the queue is of only 168 Edits. But it's 200 set for stackoverflow.

Comment: @LuFFy you would need to ask Stack Exchange to fix any caching issues, but I think it's highly unlikely that they will fix it.

Comment: lot of suggested edits are useless

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the suggested edits display in a random order, so instead of suggestions right away getting seen by the next 3 (or more) reviewers, and then moving out of the queue, you end up with a lot of suggestions, each with 1 approve/reject, and it takes longer for a suggestion to get enough votes to be marked as approved or rejected.

Comment: @TotZam I read on meta somewhere that the queues are supposed to return items in a specific order, like the CV queue is supposed to return questions with the most close votes first.  Unfortunately, that broke a long time ago and all of the original developers are gone.

Comment: @jpmc26 one of the funniest things i've seen on SO ever !

Comment: Why not have two queues: one for **hot** or **new** questions that need to be reviewed quickly because they are likely to be edited multiple times, and one for **old** questions that has no limit. The reviewers needn't know which queue was which as they are reviewing.

Comment: As someone currently trying to edit a 'First Post' to fix it, this is not helpful. If there are too many edits that need reviews, shouldn't we lower the bar for reviews so more people can help?

Comment: @KellyBang I'd rather see the bar changed than just lowered: in addition to the problem of people flying through the queue approving everything (because they just want the badge) we also have people making bad reviews because they hit 2K rep without suggesting any edits themselves, so they're not actually familiar with the rules for editing. Having a minimum number of approved suggested edits plus an overall positive percentage of approvals makes more sense than just a rep score. (I think there's a feature request for this.)

Comment: @BSMP That would be awesome: A minimum of 500 approved edits at the ratio of 99% approved before one gets the full editing privileges would get rid of most bad editors. Then the full editing privileged at 2000 reputation points can be removed entirely.

Comment: How does that fix the issue, I am trying to edit some post I encounter, it has nothing to do with the "forced edit queue chosen by stackoverflow put on you".

Comment: It would be nice if the suggested edit queue limit is increased maybe 20%, considering cached queues.

Comment: *"Go encourage 2k+ users to start reviewing edits in the queue."* <-- How can I do this? Is it possible to send a message to someone on SO? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @Milan Yes, just make a meta post and get it into HMP/featured

Comment: Thanks, @KevinB but how can I do that? Neither do I know how to make that SO post a meta post nor do I know how to get it into HMP/featured (also, what is HMP)! Sorry, I'm new to this Meta SO site. Do you have any link to a page where I can read about this? Thanks again!

Comment: In all the 5 years I have being a member, this is the first time I see, almost for two months, the message `Suggested edit queue is full`. Is there a problem? Who may I ask to check it out? Is there somewhere that shows the current state of the queue? Is there a way that I can help to reduce the number of edits in the queue?

Comment: @acarlstein No, there's not a problem; we just have a "full" queue. I was able to get some edits in a couple days ago. If you want to see the review stats, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), but apparently, it's not very accurate; the limit is 500, I'm currently getting `Suggested edit queue is full`, and only 405 edits need review as of right now. Funny that we both took notice of this within the same half hour; I happened to be here reading this answer when I saw your comment. Unfortunately, until we get 2k rep, we can't approve edits in the queue.

Comment: I continue to see `Suggested edit queue is full` routinely. Is 500 a high enough limit?

Comment: Soon, its going to be 5 years since the last time the queue was increased (June 29th, 2017). I wouldn't be surprise that the number of members has increased since then; therefore, the queue get filled up way more often. So, I agree that maybe the queue needs to be increased again.

Comment: Can we please just set it at over 9000 and be done with it?

Comment: 'encourage users with more rep' lol how should you sorry but ...

Comment: I'm getting the same message for days, and as  have checked now there are 384 items in the queue. Any hint what should I do?

Comment: @jpmc26 that website is hilarious. The answer is no.

Comment: This is a real, ongoing problem that is degrading the ability for the community to help improve site content. Raising the queue limit only helps temporarily mitigate bursty behavior, it won't help if the edit rate significantly exceeds the review rate on average for long periods. It seems clear that edit queue review needs to be further incentivized, and/or the reviewer pool needs to be increased, ie by lowering the reputation requirement to review this queue.

Comment: Suggested queue is almost always full, the only "luck"(0.0001%) I had of clicking "edit" and being prompted to `/edit` and taking my time to correct stuff (even as quick as **1 minute** (*I ALWAYS RUSH AND RISK MAKING MISTAKE OF MY OWN*) and clicking the "edit" button: I always(99.999%) got: **The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!** - it's so annoying investing your free time to make a post look cleaner and then you can't *START* editing or you can't *FINISH* editing.

Comment: This has become like eBay.  What am I supposed to do?  Repeatedly click 'Save Edits' until there happens to be a spare slot in the queue, or set up a bot to do that for me?

Comment: > "Go encourage 2k+ users to start reviewing edits in the queue."
Or maybe encourage SO/SE to change their policy.

Comment: How to participate in review and moderation process if the edit queue is mostly always full?!

Comment: "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." possible variation of the same problem?