# How come the suggested edits queue can suddenly become so big?

Tags: support, review-queues

When reviewing suggested edits today, I noticed the queue was almost at 500. That's way past the usual cap of 200.

Was that limit removed, or just increased? If the latter is the case, what is the new limit?

Also, is this a permanent change?

Comment: Can't say much, but after some internal discussions between CMs, it was bumped to a higher number. (I'll let them know of this post)

Comment: Your user name with avatar made my day! :)

Comment: @Victoria Haha, glad you like it. :)

Comment: Actually, they won't admit it, but they're trying to whip us back to caring about edit reviews, through varying means, like "Look what will happen if you keep not reviewing edits, we'll higher the limit forever".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It was increased to 500 on June 29th... for science...

In all reality, it's unlikely it will remain there. It's easy to keep arguing what we think will happen if we increase the queue size while we wait for better alternatives. So now we've tried it, and exactly what we thought would happen did happen. All we've done is increased the capacity for how much stuff is stuck in the queue. Good chance it will decrease again if/when other features are implemented. We're still working on that part.

Comment: "for science" the best reason could be given.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry, you've failed. The correct response was "You monster!"

Comment: @animuson You monster!

Comment: @Servy bah.... -1 for that comment - I'll let you off for the lack of a freehand red circle but not putting it in bold is inexcusable :)

Comment: @JonClements But animuson had said the correct answer was "You monster!" not "**You monster!**"  I didn't want to disappoint with a second incorrect answer.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Can you tell us that other features are discussed, or is that a secret? :)

Comment: Try 10000, this way it will never be full. :)

Comment: Don't be so sure, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: A queue that is never depleted will eventually get full, no matter its size. Which is why the current review system will always break, per design, if there are too few reviewers in relation to stuff to review.

Comment: This is great news; I hope it stays there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - It was a joke. Shadow Wizard did a good job picking a number, in my opinion. If it was 1000, it would be too obviously and immediately false. And if it was a million, it would be automatically dismissed as hyperbole or silliness. (Not because it wouldn't fill up, but because we would simply never increase the queue to that size.) 10000... it at least opens up the possibility that the reader has to think about it for a few seconds. I also like that a regular smiley (and not a winky) was used. Nice touch.

Comment: @JohnY, if he had said 1,000,000, I *still* would have said "don't be so sure," even if I supposed he meant it as hyperbole.

Comment: @JohnY bah, he should have used 9000...

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I think arbitrary numbers should generally not be used to model "will not be reached ever" (also think of the history of ram, 32bit, etc.). Things should be designed to either possibly be full or to be able to hold any number of elements. Even if the site is called *stack**overflow*** :)

Answer (score 28):

Yes, we increased the limit of the suggested edit queue from 200 to 500 about a week ago. With the change to the new top bar, [review has suffered greatly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link). While all the queues were impacted, the suggested edit queue was impacted the most because it blocks users from suggesting edits to posts.

Is the change permanent? Most likely not. We're actively discussing ways to alleviate some of the burden in review.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, too. Do you already know when those new changes will land?

Comment: @BaummitAugen 6-8 weeks. (perhaps days)

Comment: Per some comments on the linked Q&A, it's far from certain that the new top bar caused this problem. That was a bizarre statistical assumption.

Comment: Perhaps a temporary increase in our suggested review count per day, as well? \*wink wink nudge nudge\*

Comment: I can't say that I'm fond of the new temporary(?) limit. Having an edit pending for 5 days is just silly. And that doesn't help with "blocks users from suggesting edits". It would have been nice to be able to retract the pending edit too since the longer the edit is pending the higher the risk that it will be marked as rejected due to "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

Comment: Can't we just lower the bar for the reviews until there are enough interested people to do the reviews? I'm currently blocked on new user posts because I can't edit their question