# Was the size of the suggested edits queue reduced from 500?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

[Since June 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351727/2157772), the size of the suggested edits queue has been 500, meaning that once there are 500 suggested edits from all users, no one can suggest edits until at least one of them completes review.

I tried to suggest an edit today, but received an error message that the queue is full. However, the [review page](//stackoverflow.com/review) says that there are only 442 edits pending as of the time this question was posted, fewer than 500.

Was the size of the queue reduced today? If so, is it intentional, or a bug, and if the former, what is its current size supposed to be? (The post I linked says that the change to 500 was an experiment that was supposed to be reverted at some point, but I half-suspect it may be unintentional since it persisted for nearly four years. The previous limit was 200, for context.)

Comment: The issue you experienced is probably due to caching.

Comment: @TylerH Nope, I refreshed the review page and the count updated to 427. Yet I'm still unable to suggest edits because the queue is full.

Comment: IIRC, the number of pending reviews is fuzzed a bit so it isn't an exact count.

Comment: @gparyani The cache is server-side too.

Comment: Did you hard refresh or normal refresh, @gparyani? I don't think even a hard refresh can fix caching... but I'm not an expert in these matters. AFAIK, caching is server based and refreshing doesn't help much.

Comment: informational SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1386799?start=2021-01-01&end=2021-03-14#graph

Comment: @rene the number of suggested edits in that graph is often more than 500!

Comment: However big it may be at the moment, it seems to be too small, every time, every few months, i suggest an edit, it says it was full. And for obvious reasons, it stays that way for a while.

Answer (score 21):

The limit is still 500 - I currently see there being 490, which is pretty darn close.

Here's the site setting, which hasn't been touched since 2017 when Shog set it to 500 -

[image: screenshot of the site setting for max items in the suggested edits review queue on SO]

Here's what I see in the queue currently:

[image: Screenshot of the review queue list showing 490 items in the suggested edits review queue]

Even if we had changed it, lowering it to ~450 seems a bit odd? More and more it seems like people are not able to submit reviews since this queue is full.

I'm curious if there are reasons that this queue is full so often - I haven't looked at any data about it but it definitely seems like something we need to address - and not by changing the limit of suggested edits. If few people are reviewing these, then we need to find ways to get people to review more regularly. I find suggested edits are *generally* fairly simple reviews, though I'm not generally on SO - which I could understand them being more complicated to review.

Comment: I expect the new review user interface is not helping making people want to review. The big radio-button box is taking up 1/3 of the screen leaving a very narrow view screen for a side-to-side view of a post. This means one has to scroll all the time. When there's code in a post it's even worse. To be able to see the top right side of a code block, you have to scroll down to the bottom of the block first. Then scroll right. Then revert the scroll to see the nest bits.. and so it goes. I personally just clicked the X in on the top right of the window, and am now waiting for a better UI :)

Comment: Why do different numbers show for <2k users vs. 2k+ users? At the same time as I was seeing 442, another 2k+ user reported seeing 489. Even so, both numbers are less than 500.

Comment: @gparyani No clue. I saw 489 for a while and then it changed to 490. I'd also point out that I'm not a 2k user. ;)

Comment: Probably as you have moderator rights here, you get the same rights as 2k+ users, which may include numbers that match them. If you view the page while logged out, you'll see the other number.

Comment: I concur, anecdotally, that the limit feels like it's been hit a lot recently. I'd love to see some hard data about the queue total over time though.

Comment: @Scratte I do understand that - I know the side-by-side is a point of friction for some people, particularly on longer posts, where more scrolling may be necessary.

Comment: @zcoop98 I would like to see what data we collect - I've asked internally whether we collect data about how many suggested edit attempts get blocked and how often the queue is full - hopefully that will help us get some insight. We can probably look at the top reviewers in that queue from before the change and talk to them about their experience, particularly if their numbers are a big drop from where they were prior to the change.

Comment: @Catija I don't mind side-by-side at all. But I mind that 1/3 of the screen is being used for something that is unrelated to the post I'm reviewing. The new user interface has made is unnecessarily hard to review suggested edits. Try it yourself.. remember you *have* to check if any changes was made to code.

Comment: @Scratte That's a fair distinction - it's less the side-by-side and more how narrow each section is. And it's the new right sidebar in review that exacerbates that issue, right? Essentially, the red/orange sections in this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDc3.png)

Comment: FWIW, suggested edits depend on a particularly sensitive bit of logic that tries to ensure no two people review the same edit at the same time. When that works, it should increase throughput by minimizing wasted reviews - but I've seen issues in the past where scores or hundreds of tasks will end up "locked" even after their reviewers have reviewed. A lot has probably changed with y'all's Redis configuration over the past year, so I don't want to speculate - but worth checking out.

Comment: @Catija I hadn't noticed the red sections. I have a small screen. This is a screen shot of [my full window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwCAG.png). I've jokingly said that it's a waste of time reviewing posts 4 words per line. I can see that it's actually 8 :O For me, the orange section with the radio-button box has to go and leave the spot for the review. I can do it using my add blocker, but then I can't submit my verdict :D I was hoping someone else would be equally dissatisfied and created a user script that gave me the buttons back. No such luck so far.. perhaps they're waiting too.

Comment: @Shog9 I just checked on our ActiveReviewItems cache (used on all queues, not just Suggested Edits). Looks like things are healthy - we have on average about 10 items being expired from there for Suggested Edits every 5 minute sync. So doesn't appear to be a big pileup there, at least nothing that would explain this.

Comment: "*I'm curious if there are reasons that this queue is full so often*" I assume it's just people submitting edit suggestions at a higher rate than people are reviewing them since suggesting edits is one of the queue item creation paths that people are *forced* to walk for the longest duration (up to 2k reputation), so it's something more people run into more often, for potentially *years* of participation on the site.

Comment: I bet the community would be happy with doubling the limit to 1,000, but I don't know why it was ever set so low in the first place (costly on the backend?)

Comment: Right on, @Yaakov - that just leaves the input vs output to monitor! Should be some stuff from Jon around for that purpose.

Comment: @TylerH it is not particularly costly on the backend. It is more: try to ensure that items that reach the queue are reviewed in a timely fashion.

Comment: The problem is that the backlog itself changes behavior, @tyler - if folks have to wait on pending edits, it holds up other work.

Comment: @TylerH that definitely touches on something that I've been thinking a ton about - how privileges are gate-kept by reputation... there's definitely people who have submitted many edits and had most of them approved but just haven't hit the 2k rep... which essentially means we're creating this issue to some degree. I'd love to see a future where privilege is more directly tied to experience with a tool, not pure reputation. So, users with <2K maybe get full edit privileges because they have >90% approved and a minimum of 50 suggestions or something like that.

Comment: @YaakovEllis the cost of that choice is that many items are not reviewed *ever* because they aren't *allowed* in the queue in the first place. That's the bad UX at stake here--we tell users "anyone can edit stuff to improve it, and users review your edits when you're below 2k to make sure they're improvements"... but then we often just shut the door and say "sorry, not today". On occasion I encounter posts with pending edits in the wild and I review them then and there without having to go to the review queue. This arguably useful behavior might occur more often, if we let it.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know what you mean by work getting held up. Users can't suggest an edit and then go on about their day doing other things?

Comment: @Catija I'm definitely a big fan of more intelligently gating thresholds based on a user's prior body of work in the relevant area. Suggested edits is one area that could benefit from this. Flagging and close/reopen voting are others.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Off the top of my head I would assume we could perfectly solve the "items in the queue get reviewed in a timely fashion" concern by simply sorting queue items by datetime, FIFO-style. The longer something's been in the queue, the higher it is on the list of items to show to users.

Comment: Two things, @TylerH: (1) no one can edit a post while a suggested edit is pending (there's an exception for "improve" edits, but you gotta have full edit rights to use that and can't have already "approved" or "rejected"). (2) each editor may have only so many pending edits at any given time; if it takes hours or days for them to be reviewed, they must stop editing.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know that someone not being able to edit a post because there's a pending edit on it is really a problem? I know we can't track when people *don't* do something, but we don't have many Meta complaints on it IIRC. Likewise I don't think it's an issue to say "hey you've suggested 20 improvements today, you can suggest more tomorrow". At least, it isn't nearly as bad as "hey you haven't met your limit yet, but we still aren't going to let you submit an edit". On that note we could just double the limit of pending suggestions at the same time as doubling the queue size to 1000.

Comment: As you say, it's hard to know how often someone sees a post that needs an edit but has a pending edit and just... Walks away, @TylerH. However, it is possible to gauge the effect by looking at how edit submission rates vary with queue size. I suspect that if there was no hard limit for the queue we'd find some natural point at which edits stalled, similar to what is seen for bounties; but unlike bounties, suggested edits don't "time out" - so in practice that point would tend to gradually increase over time anyway, even as the rate of new edits continued to decrease.

Comment: ...in any case, raising or increasing the limit doesn't fix anything. 500 was supposed to be a *temporary* measure while we fixed [the massive decrease in reviewing triggered by the top-bar redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link). Obviously, that didn't really happen, not to the extent that was needed. Now the new limit is insufficient. Maybe 1K would buy a bit more time, but... Eventually it too will be insufficient unless the underlying issue is addressed.

Comment: Further reading, @TylerH: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown

Comment: Suggested edits is actually my favorite review queue, I stopped reviewing there because close-vote reviewing seems more pressing and I only have that much time to spend on moderating. So I keep casting CVs but have largely stopped reviewing suggested edits, although I'd prefer it be the other way around. In any case, I'd also be close to another steward gold badge for reviewing in both queues but I have mixed feelings about getting more Steward badges, so I decided to moderate/review outside the queues.

Comment: One of the problems with reviewing suggested edits is the possibility of revenge downvotes when rejecting a suggestion. Although I have no *hard* evidence, I have experienced this quite frequently. The rep. loss doesn't really bother me, but those few questions I have to my name have scores lower than I would expect, due to this "cheap" downvote action (many of the downvotes on my questions have come in pairs - two DVs will not activate the reversal script).  ...

Comment: ... I now frequently "skip" reviews that I *should* reject, if the editor has >125 rep. Others may do the same - dunno. Maybe anonymizing (or partially so, as in Close Votes) would be a way to get more reviews done? It would certainly encourage me to reject (and thus help to *complete*) more reviews.

Answer (score 17):

The number that is shown to you (in this case: 442) is the number of items in the queue that are not in the list of items being actively reviewed at the moment (items are inserted there when loaded by a user, and removed when the user finishes their review, or they expire after 3 minutes and are then removed in an every-5-minute sync). So when you saw 442, the actual number of items in the queue (including those being reviewed) was definitely higher. The diff between actual numbers and the number you will see will vary over time (based on how many people are currently reviewing).

As far as enforcing the limit on max items per queue (currently 500), current logic is: there is a query that runs once a minute checking on the number of items in the queue. This number is cached for 500 seconds (8.33 minutes). If this number is over the limit, then all suggested edits will be rejected until the next time that this number is refreshed.

So in a situation where queue was over the limit, and you submitted your edit close to the cache expiration (let's say: 7 minutes after it was calculated) - the real number of items in the queue that moment could definitely have been lower than 500. That plus the number of active reviews is how you could get the "queue is full" message at the same time as seeing 442 items in the queue.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation, but why don't you show the cached number for <2k users?

Answer (score 4):

How about we lower the amount of reputation needed? As every time when I start reviewing the groups I am allowed to review, I eventually get blocked by this issue. As a starting reviewer, this blockade really brings down my motivation to help improve the platform.

Reducing the amount of reputation required, would simply enable more people to work on the queue.

To make things clear, I "only" have ~615 reputation and don't suggest lowering it that low. But maybe it makes sense to switch it with `create tags` (1500 reputation) as in my opinion we require more reviewers, and not that many new tags.

Comment: The would require something else to change as well. 1500 rep users can't edit posts without their edits being reviewed. Do we just lower the rep that editing privileges are given at? Do we give them only two options in review (accept/reject), like in lower rep tag wiki reviews?

Comment: My suggestion was to simply lower the 2000 to 1500. So everything that now is limited to 2000, will be limited to 1500. It could be tried with your suggestion, though I don't know how effective that would be for what we try to achieve here.