# Could the suggested edits cap limit get increased with positive edit suggestions rating?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

As of late I've been pretty active in the review queues myself. 
Editing a lot of newbie questions, adding tags, formatting, changing to more fitting titles You know the drill..

Thing is, I've lately ran up numerous times against the arbitrary pending edits cap:

[image]

---

Now, although what I'm about to say may sound a bit self-entitled, but hear me out:
I feel like, given my positive edit suggestions history:

[image]

I should be provided **more than 4 pending suggestions max**.
I feel like I've proven that I am capable of providing meaningful edits that do improve the quality of the questions/answers  at hand.

---

Now, I do understand why this precaution exists. It discourages users from arbitrary edits or straight out abusing the system and spamming the edit review queue with meaningless edits, but I feel like the **edit cap should be increased with positive edit suggestions history** similarly how it works with the current flagging system.

The [flags incrementation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) system works currently the following way

> **How many flags do I have?**
>   When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day.
>    This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus
>     declined flags).

Obviously, maybe not with the exact same numbers per edit increment, but at least some. I don't see **why I should be prevented from positively contributing**!

Comment: And I'm genuinely curious why the question is currently at -3 points. It's not that I mind the downvotes, but I'd like to at least know, what is so wrong with it or what am I missing that makes this a bad question. At least leave a comment, if there's something wrong with it, so I might get an idea why.

Comment: I don't think approval rate is a good measurement of the quality of someones edits. I have seen too many edits that fixed one thing but left 99 other things untouched get approved.

Comment: Side note: please note that Meta voting on feature requests indicates agreement or disagreement (so please don't take the downvotes personally).

Comment: @AndréKool Perhaps not. Though it's the best indicator I can at least think of. Do you per chance have anythign else in mind that would prove a better indicator?

Comment: Considering you are 77 rep away from not having suggested edits and having your edits go through.... Is it really that needed?  Anyway I echo André here.... The edit review queue lets through **so much** bad edits through, that I don't think having a good ratio is an indicator of much :/

Comment: I don't think this topic is particularly about me or my situation. It's not particularly needed for me (or it soon won't), but I feel like it is artifficially preventing valuable input from other newer members. Perhaps my view on things will change upon gaining access to edit queue

Answer (score -1):

Aside from wanting to [prevent a user from blasting the queue with a ton of small edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits), there is a limit on the total number of edits that can be in the queue at one time. [Stack Overflow's Suggested Edit Queue limit is 500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full/345157#345157).

We don't want the Suggested Edit Queue to get full because it frustrates users who are doing other moderation tasks. See this comment from the link above:

> Currently shows the edit queue is full, when there's 92 listed. I'm
>   done trying to improve first posts and things, because every time I
>   do, I can't ever send my edits in -- So forget it, helping new posters
>   isn't worth my time anymore, they are just going to have to do it
>   right themselves. – gattsbr Jun 27 '17 at 19:12