# This answer needs an edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I never heard of the suggested edit queue before, maybe because I don't edit a lot of answers. But I heard of it just now because there's an answer with a glaring flaw:

- *Timing Delays in VBA*: [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960434/timing-delays-in-vba/#6960716)

The answer was edited by its author to correct a flaw pointed out in a comment, but the "correction" is wrong. It tests for `Timer = 0`, which will almost never happen. It should instead test for `Timer < Start`. Another answer tried a correction of `Timer >= 86399`, but that test can also fail on a slow computer.

I wanted to propose an edit to correct it, but I can't because the suggested edit queue is full.

I guess a lot of other people have also seen this problem, which is why you have over 500 suggested edits. But this is pretty crazy. You've got an accepted answer sitting there with a glaring error, and 500 people have presumably tried to fix it, but it sits there, wrong.

What can be done to correct the bug in the code of the accepted answer?

Comment: This post is composed almost entirely of misconceptions about how the site, review queues, and suggested edits, work. Anyway, do you have a question to ask? All I see is a rant about how unimpressed you are with the curation on the site. If this post is literally to point out that an answer needs an edit, why don't you make the edit yourself?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I tried to edit the answer, but got a message that the suggested edit queue is full. Some research told me that the queue size is 500 and that I need 2k reputation to even view the queue. So yes, my post is a rant about not being able to correct a glaring error in an accepted answer. But if there's something I don't understand, and there's something I should have done to be able to make the edit, please tell me. In fact, I'll edit the post to ask that question.

Comment: Yes, the queue is 500 in capacity, _for the site, across the 50 million undeleted posts_ (plus some deleted posts and tag edits). There have only ever been 3 attempts to edit that answer, all of which occured in 2013.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your question doesn't mention that the suggested edit queue is full; so you should add that to this question. In general, you just have to wait a bit for the queue to empty up a bit. In this particular case, you shouldn't make the edit, as that would change the author's intent. If you think the answer is wrong, leave a comment saying that, and downvote the answer.

Comment: So what exactly _is_ your question?

Comment: I don't need to argue with you about how to run your site. I presume it was not the author's intent to include a bug in his code. My intention was to correct the bug and add a note indicating that the edit had been made and why. In any case, it appears that I wouldn't be allowed to edit the answer anyway because three other people (not 500 apparently, thank you for the correction Nick) have tried and it still sits there unedited.

Comment: Of the 3 edits, one posted an entirely new version of the code below the original, and should've been a new answer. The second had no explanation of the fix or why it was necessary, and the 3rd was just a repeat of the second with a description of the changes (which is useless, we can see them in the queue) but without really an explanation of how it fixed the problem. None of them were particularly good, and as I said, all 3 were over 8 years ago now

Comment: And you misunderstood my first comment, I was just saying 3 had attempted to fix it, you _are_ welcome to attempt to edit it when the queue is no longer at its capacity (of 500 _between all posts on the site_), but prepare to be disappointed if the edit you suggest isn't a good one. _Dont_ include that you've made an edit in the edit body, nor why (users coming across the post need it to be correct, not read meta commentary about why it was wrong but no longer is). Explain the edit with detail in the edit _comment_ field.

Comment: While you guys are downvoting this post and criticizing me for not understanding how the site works, please note that when I clicked on "Edit", I got a message that the suggested edit queue was full, with no explanation of what that means. I Googled it and found some stuff, and it's not surprising that what I found didn't fully explain the situation. So you might want to put a link on the queue-is-full message to a documentation page that explains what you would have wanted me to know before ranting at you.

Comment: As for fixing it when the queue dies down, I don't come here often, so I don't know when I'll ever see that Q&A again. I come here when I need help, and I do what I can to pitch in with answers when I can. I was trying to do that today by correcting that error.

Comment: Your search should have lead you here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work. Probably via here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ after you decided to look up "What is the suggested edit queue"

Comment: Googling the error message gets me https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full which at least contains the beginnings of an explanation through the links.

Comment: Ultimately answer is: Queue is full? Sorry, come back later. If you don't come back later, it clearly wasn't very important an edit.

Comment: @NewSites some clarifications: while we (the community) can be said "running" this site, it just means that we can only use the features that the developers (who have limited resources) provided. Some things are just out of our (the community)'s control, even as trivial as "put(ting) a link on the queue-is-full message to a documentation page".

Comment: It's perfectly fine if an edit cannot be made/suggested by you specifically though; you're among a huge group of people here. Someone else will see it sooner or later.

Comment: @NewSites - re: waiting - you can follow the post you wanted to edit, then it will always be accessible in the "following" tab of the profile page. You will also have the benefit of getting a notification if somebody edits it in shape in the meantime.

Comment: @NewSites - re: voting - please note that voters on Meta act differently: votes do not affect your reputation here, nor can you get post-banned for badly-received posts. You grossly misunderstood what the feature means and made a ranty post here - for which 12 *random people on the net* reacted with "I don't think it's useful". That's all there is.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unable to suggest the edit yourself, leave a comment to explain what's wrong. Somebody who understands the technology and has the privileges to edit without going through the queue can see your comment and make an edit. (But I agree that it sucks that the suggested edits queue is full so often.)

Comment: I did leave a comment on the answer with a link to this post, where I explained the problem, so I hope one of you guys will do what you said could happen, and edit the answer. Thank you. (But note that you can't just change `Timer = 0` to `Timer < Start`. That change requires some other changes, which I've tested in my code.)

Comment: Sounds like you should be submitting your own answer if it requires modification of more than a single line.  Accepted answers are sometimes wrong, which is the reason it should be downvoted, and the correct answer should be submitted