# How to show queue "Suggested edit queue is full"

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Something about Suggested edit queue is full, can be found here:
[Suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full)

I would like to have ability to show suggest queue and to use something of suggestions. Is it possible? I would also like to make review if possible.

My current "full queue" is on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64353288/11152683

Comment: There isn't one queue for each post. It's one queue *total* for all suggested edits for all posts *and* for all tag wikis + excerpts for the entire site.

Comment: [Can I review pending edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97363)

Comment: You mean, that given answer (which I would like to edit) could have zero pending edits on it? I am willing to edit it and improve, but I can :/ So leaving just comments with partial info.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit of 500 pending edits *total* for the entire site. And if you try to suggest a new one, you'd get the message that a queue is full. Well, maybe not precisely [due to caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) but close enough. Moreover, you *cannot* suggest an edit to a post that already has a suggested edit. It's only one edit at a time per post. Even with full edit privileges, you cannot directly edit a post while it has a suggestion pending. You need to wait for it to be resolved. You can at least review it.

Answer (score 2):

As VLAZ commented out, there is "global" queue for all suggested edits and there is perhaps no edit pending for given answer. I can just wait to be able to edit answer (others will free suggest queue), or if I have enough permissions, I can help review some things (just next to recent achievements icon).

Comment: There is an error prior to editing if the queue is full, but spots in it aren't reserved when "edit" is pressed. If it fills up in the meanwhile, the error appears when submitting instead of when trying to start