# Why does the Stack Overflow logo link not retain https if that is what the user is using?

Tags: discussion, ssl, user-experience

You can use Stack Overflow over TLS by prefixing https:// to any URL on the domain. This works well, and any links on the site are structured to retain https.

That is except for the logo. If you click the logo to return to the homepage, the link explicitly removes https, and reverts back to http. It is a bit annoying. Is there a chance of this getting fixed? Is there a reason that it is setup this way?

[image]

Comment: The current status of the HTTPS move: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time