# Replace http links in tag wikis to https

Tags: discussion, ssl

As Stack Overflow moved to https and migrated all http to https links in questions and answers (cf. [HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time)), links to `stackoverflow.com` on tag info pages were not yet migrated.

When doing this, also links to Wikipedia could be migrated to https.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info

Comment: (Partial) duplicate of feature request on the uber-Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300235/convert-http-links-to-https-in-tag-wikis

Comment: You can move links to external sites such as Wikipedia from http to https *entirely independently* from this site supporting https. The two are not connected. I don't think a script to fix stack links should touch  other links.

Comment: But when I'm on a https site and I'd like not to have links to https as this could leak information.

Comment: @MrTux: but it's fine if you are on a http site? It's still an independent task.

Comment: I'm all with you, MrTux, but it will be a few years from now before I get Tag Edit Privilege (20K Rep).