# "Insert Hyperlink" window still shows http instead of https

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

When writing or editing a post and inserting a hyperlink via the toolbar or keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> you get this window:

[image]

It still shows `http://example.com/` and the `http://` prefix. I checked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time) todo-list, but it's not mentioned there.

Proposal: change the example url and prefix to `https://`.

Comment: What if you *want* to link to http instead of https? Pretty much every site that supports https will put you on the https link from the http link (in one way or another). Trying to access something that doesn't support https will lead to surprising results and potentially broken links if the poster doesn't notice to remove the "s"... eg: one way (the current one) it'll most likely work if you get it not quite right - the other way it won't...

Comment: Having said that though - I find it a little hard to believe that anyone actually *types* into that box rather than just copy/pasting from somewhere (most likely from the address bar of a page they currently have open)... so the whole http/https thing is  likely a moot point anyway...

Comment: @JonClements those are good points I didn't think about carefully enough. I just recognized it as an UI-mismatch: we want secure links on SO, we even did a lot of work to change links in existing posts, and here we _suggest to use_ http again. I just thought it's worth mentioning.

Comment: It's probably better just to replace the pre-filled text with a  `placeholder` attribute for the input element.

Comment: I didn't even know there is such window, get used to type `[ ]( )` myself, because comments don't have such function anyway. I'd remove window, so it will insert `[title](url)` or something. Insert picture is more useful because it's combined with upload (browse button).

Comment: @JonClements But it does feel like you're promoting bad practice by defaulting to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: While mentioning the dialog, it would be great with a link description aswell if you have not selected any text. Also goes for the image popup

Comment: Does SO validate the links entered?  If so, maybe it could check to see if there's an HTTPS version available and if so automatically switch?  If not, my suggestion probably adds additional overhead to a simple UI requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has since been fixed - sorry for the late meta update!