# Wikipedia links not https, is there a special reason they shouldn't?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, external-links, ssl

While editing [this answer to a generic question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279678/479251), I was adding Wikipedia links, I noticed that the other existing (also Wikipedia) links where all HTTP, though mine were HTTPS.

Shouldn't they have been [changed to HTTPS when](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time) [Stack Overflow went HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/22/stack-overflow-flipped-switch-https/)?

Or maybe should they stay HTTP, because they are not image or some other reason (though I don't understand why)?

Or are they simply waiting for someone to edit them while passing by?

Is there anything we / devs should do about it?

Comment: I guess we're now in an era where it doesn't occur to certain people that not every site was always HTTPS...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, the HTTPS change only applied to Stack Exchange links.

SE has no idea which sites do and don't support HTTP. It'd be a bad idea to replace every single link in every single answer like that.

If you happen to be editing something where you see links that can be updated, I'd suggest you do.

Comment: manual edit it is, then! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Pac0 yes, just verify each link individually before adding the `s`. It's safe for Wikipedia, Google, Imgur and plenty others, but even for some big corps like Microsoft, I've noticed that _sometimes_ it's breaking the link.

Comment: With that said, I think we all know Wikipedia does *now*. As a major site that is now well known to support HTTPS, does it make sense to open a discussion about replace Wikipedia links and maybe a couple other major sites (e.g., GitHub)? Although, if they support HSTS, maybe it's a waste. Not to mention the, "Where does it end?" problem. I dunno, but maybe worth posing the question.

Comment: @jpmc26: Wikipedia does implement HSTS.

Comment: @Cœur I sure did check the links, and indeed, Wikipedia is one of the major world website that *probably* ([SEDE citation needed]) has a a big number of links to it in Stack Overflow and the other SE sites. Since it is known that they went all HTTPS too, updating these particular links certainly looks the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Pac0: Absolutely the correct thing to do, though I should add that it's not terribly urgent since, as I mentioned, the site implements HSTS, and guarantees that anyone using a modern browser never actually goes through an HTTP link to it (unless they're so new to the Internet, as is the case with an alarming number of SO users, that they've never been there before). As in, ideally all the links would be updated, but it's acceptable to update them only as you come across them instead of seeking out and updating every last one.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you're editing was written in 2009.

[Wikipedia didn't officially support HTTPS at all until 2011](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2011/10/03/native-https-support-enabled-for-all-wikimedia-foundation-wikis/), and [it wasn't on by default until 2015](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2015/06/12/securing-wikimedia-sites-with-https/).

As others have mentioned, Stack Overflow's conversion to HTTPS only affected links to Stack Overflow. It didn't modify links to other web sites.

Comment: Before that, it began redirecting users using HTTPS through a separate `https://secure.wikimedia.org/` URL.

Comment: @gparyani The first 2011 transition I'm referring to was when they stopped requiring that. HTTPS service through secure.wikimedia.org was available earlier, but was unreliable and effectively "unofficial".

Comment: @gparyani that reminds me of https://secure.php.net/.