# Community edit not using best practice

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-user

I understand that Community is a bot that does some cleaning and some organising jobs here and there. I've read [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18018102/revisions). I've always been told that you should always use permalink (share link) to refer to other post as URL could change.

Should the Community bot replace link with title and permalink instead of just title?

Or do I miss something?

---

I may have explained incorrectly. I though everyone should use link in the permalink form:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367995/1195001
```

[Community edit not using best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367995/1195001)
and not links in the URL:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/community-edit-not-using-best-practice
```

[Community edit not using best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/community-edit-not-using-best-practice)
I don't care that much about **https in this case**, only the type of link that should be used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Links to questions are automagically expanded. Community did the right thing there. No need for the edit

Comment: @rene OK my bad. it seems odd to me that such an obvious bug was there.

Comment: This edit is part of a one time batch job converting all http links to https. I don't think it involved anything other than adding the letter `s`.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the HTTPS/HTTPS links question.

Comment: `I've always been told that you should always use permalink (share link) to refer to other post as url could change`.  I've never heard that statement.  Could you explain where you learned of this "best practice"

Comment: @psubsee2003 while using stackexchange site a bit of here and there that something I've read several time I now know it's incorrect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The side-by-side markdown view of the edit makes what was changed clearer - it was only `http` => `https`, nothing else (as per [the move to HTTPS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time)).

[image]

Raw URLs of Stack Exchange questions (on the same site) are automatically converted to the title.

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/community-edit-not-using-best-practice
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367995/1711796
```

Displays as:

[Community edit not using best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/community-edit-not-using-best-practice)
[Community edit not using best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367995/1711796)

The reason the display changed from a URL to a title is because the URL to title conversion only happens during editing - if the post managed to be saved with an unconverted raw URL, it will remain so until it's edited. I'm not sure why the initial post didn't convert the raw URL to a title though (this feature has existed since before the answer was posted).

See also: [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title)

---

Also, while post URLs change with the title, that doesn't invalidate any URLs since Stack Exchange ignores the title / last part of the URL.

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/it-doesnt-matter-what-i-write-here
```

[Still links to this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367995/it-doesnt-matter-what-i-write-here), even though the title doesn't match.