# Http flair link

Tags: bug, ssl

The Normal Flair links are set to http, not https. Shouldn't that be changed?

[image]

Comment: That is part of the http to https change and IIRC the flair change has been made thrice and rolled back the same amount of times.

Comment: Should be fixed somewhere in [this timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

Comment: Lol any specific reasoning?

Comment: I'm not sure about the technical details but I wouldn't be surprised if this is in the same category as [HandleSuccess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207388/why-is-the-handlesuccess-method-such-a-terrible-one) ...

Comment: [It was already discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343298).