# Community and HTTPS URLS

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I notice many times that the community moderator, when she edits a question or an answer she focus on URLs which do not start with `https`; she always change `http` to `https`. Here is an example this post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/344068/revisions):

[image: Community edit]

---

Is there a reason for that, is that for security purposes, or why exactly?

Comment: You do know that the "community moderator" is not a person, right?

Comment: nope, i don't @Oded really **"community moderator" is not a person** ?

Comment: The way you phrased your question suggests that.

Comment: so he is a person or robot, and why he change that always @Oded this is my question!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images

Comment: Was going to DV, but..... freehand red circles. The meta is strong...

Comment: Weird, this seems like a completely reasonable question to me.

Comment: @YCF_L "Community" is not a person. Check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the network sites are moving to HTTPS (Stack Overflow is scheduled to move soon).

The reason we have been rewriting all the links to Stack Exchange sites to use HTTPS over HTTP is so we (and you) don't incur the cost of a redirects from HTTP to HTTPS once the move is done.

That is - once the sites *enforce* HTTPS, if you access the site over HTTP, you will get redirected to HTTPS - that's an extra roundtrip that we don't want to do.

Comment: i see this is good so we should to try always use https instead of http in our urls right?

Comment: For links that go into the Stack Exchange network, yes. I'd say always, but not every site supports HTTPS...

Comment: i got it thank you for the answer