# Should protocol-relative URLs be disallowed in profile "About me"?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, images, ssl

Unexpected error message when opening “About me” for editing:

```
All image URLs must start with https://
```

This is triggered by the existing protocol-relative URLs in the “About me” text for my user profile, which were previously legal, but apparently not legal anymore.

I’d report this with the [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag except I don’t know if this is a bug. It might turn out that protocol-relative URLs in profile images are actually a bad thing, so I’m asking for discussion.

It seems maybe a bit ironic, or a step back. I elected years ago to use protocol-relative URLs for images. When SE transitioned from `http` to `https` protocol these URLs transitioned perfectly to `https` as well … they work as intended, but if I ever want to edit my profile again I’ll have to eliminate them.

Comment: @davidism The other value in my case is parsimony. That's seven expensive bytes per image URL.

Comment: Agreed, it should let you use protocol relative URL's, even if http is explicitly disallowed. Maybe simplify the check to make sure the URL does *not* start with `http:`. And forget protocol-relative URLs, what if you want to link to an image on stackoverflow.com for some reason? You should be able to use domain-relative URLs too.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - there aren't any/many images hosted on the SO domain. User uploaded ones are hosted at `i.stack.imgur.com` and most/all others are served from `cdn.sstatic.net`

Comment: `http://` images will be blocked anyways.

Comment: Related post [HTTPS-only images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343276/2451726)

Comment: @KodosJohnson: To clarify what Martin Smith said, both of those hosting domains support HTTPS. So there is never any reason to use protocol-relative image URLs anymore, and they're an attractive anti-pattern; if the image is HTTPS-hosted, it's fine to use that, and if not, it won't work anyway for users and needs to be re-uploaded somewhere that supports HTTPS. Like SE's own imgur hosting.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks, I didn't think about http images not working on https.