# Why don't Stack Overflow tag pages have a canonical link tag?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, seo

Stack Overflow is available with an HTTPS version, [so by default Google will index the HTTPS version.](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/12/indexing-https-pages-by-default.html)

Now the problem is all Stack Overflow questions do have a canonical link tag with HTTP (`<link rel="canonical">`), which says please index the HTTP version, instead of HTTPS in SERP (search engine results page). But the tag pages do not contain any canonical link tag, which may cause mixing HTTP and HTTPS version in SERP.

Search on Google `site:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/`

Such a thing increases the crawl rate for Stack Overflow and Googlebot may consume more bandwidth.

Comment: SO is crawled at a very high speed, questions posted can appear in Google only a minute later. And I doubt Googlebot has to worry about bandwidth.

Comment: In addition, HTTPS support is still a work in progress. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com for example.

Comment: @Stijn I am talking about canonical link tag, which is not present on tags pages. I already read that question. Googlebot does not have to worry about bandwidth, SO have to, because same pages(http/https) will be crawl twice. Please first read the question properly, before downvote :(

Comment: I didn't vote on your question (yet).