# Why doesn't Stack Exchange have an SSL certificate yet?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is a pretty big thing on the Internet, yet I find no SSL on any of its websites, like Stack Overflow, Super User, etc.

It seems ironic that Stack Overflow often helps people get going with SSL on their websites, yet has no SSL for itself.

Comment: I don't follow. You can access most sites over https already. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Uh, it has one. https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: By default it does not direct to `https` though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Stack Overflow default to SSL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255604/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-default-to-ssl),  [https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: Why should it default to https? What's the benefit, given that https *requires* an extra round trip (increasing latency - for some people quite significantly)?

Comment: @Oded - Aaaaah! You doesn't Google think the same, then ?

Comment: We are not Google. And we don't do things just because "everyone else does it".

Comment: Okay. But, I find that to be a practice though.

Comment: "a practice". Do you mean "best practise"? Without *any* proper context?

Comment: I just mean 'Practice' as in plain, simple PRACTICE. You already told, why it isn't the "Best Practice.

Comment: Not a particularly useful distinction - that's like saying people do "stuff".

Comment: @oded You should do more "stuff." I like stuff. Stuff is good.

Comment: @CodyGray - working on more stuff. Just for you.

Comment: @Oded - Good luck for the stuff !

Comment: To be clear - we do intend to fully support https. As and when that happens, we shouldn't throw people who _are_ on https to http. But - I don't expect us to _default_ to https - certainly not to start with (given the extra latency and our focus on performance)